# What are the pros/cons of this class definition style?

Tags: c++, typedef

I have seen following style class definition several times. What exactly are the pros/cons of this style?

```
typedef class _MyClass
{
public :
  _MyClass();
} MyClass;
```

Comment: First con: `_MyClass` is a identifier reserved for the implementation (compiler + standard libs). In user code it is incorrect to use it. A related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions) (the question is tagged C, the first answer is both C and C++, explaining the differences)

Comment: This is a leftover from a C developer who had not learned how to use C++ correctly. Ignore it. There are absolutely no benefits from type-defing a class or struct in C++

Comment: Also: dont use a prefix _ unless you really know when it is bad: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty rare in C++, but common in C (where `struct Foo` does not automatically alias to just `Foo`.) You might see it in a library that has different classes for different platforms (e.g. a "Canvas" class, which is very implementation-specific.) The library would use the `typedef` to let its users simplify their code:

```
#if WINDOWS
    typedef class WindowsCanvas {
        private: HWND handle;
    } Canvas;
#elif MAC
    typedef class MacCanvas {
        private: CGContextRef context;
    } Canvas;
#endif
```

In such an example, one would only need to use the `Canvas` type, never the platform-specific types.

Comment: I think your example doesn't prove anything. One could just NAME the classes with Canvas in both cases

Comment: I know that. :) But some people prefer that style. It *does* make a difference in debugging, where the debugger will typically know the name of a class, but not its `typedef` aliases, making it potentially easier to know which implementation is in use.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ there are no pros. This style came from C where you couldn't just use the struct's name as a type. E.g.

```
struct X
{
   int x;
};

X a; //compiler error
struct X b; //OK
```

in order to avoid using the elaborated type specifier, like `struct X a`, or `enum E e;` etc. in C it is a common practice to typedef the name. 
E.G.

```
typedef struct X_ { ... } X;
```

Now `X a;` is OK too.

Naturally in C++ there is no need to do this.

Comment: Incorrect.  In C, `typedef struct foo foo;` is valid.  The `typedef struct _foo foo;` idiom is actually a workaround for C++, since C++ has an implicit `typedef` for every `struct`/`class` declaration, so the `typedef` cannot have the same name as the `struct`.

Comment: In C++ there are no pros - some explanation will be helpful.

Comment: @asveikau: Huh? typedef struct foo foo; is valid in C++ as well

Comment: @Chubsdad: The explanation is the rationale of this style in C and the absence of such need on C++.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: oh ok. I am not sure, but seem to find $7.1.3/6 as an advantage

Comment: @asveikau: That is a common misconception, the short answer is no, there is no implicit typedef in C++, the difference is that after failing to match an identifier in the non-types name space it will proceed to lookup the identifier in the user defined types name space (name space here does not denote a c++ `namespace` but rather a set of identifiers of a given kind in the compiler). See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

Answer (score 2):

One possible advantage is illustrated by a highly contrived example, but since the Standard speaks of it, it must be having an impliciation for sure.

> $7.1.3/6- "Similarly, in a given
>   scope, a class or enumeration shall
>   not be declared with the same name as
>   a typedef-name that is declared in
>   that scope and refers to a type other
>   than the class or enumeration itself.
>   [

```
typedef struct S{} MYS;

int MYS;                     // Error due to $7.1.3/6

struct A{};

int A;                       // No error, subsequent use required fully elaborated name

int main(){}
```

Comment: Don't see that as an advantage.