# C Struct : typedef Doubt !

Tags: c, struct, typedef

In the given code snippet, I expected the error `symbol Record not found`. But it compiled and ran fine on Visual Studio 2010 Compiler. I ran it as a C program from Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt in the manner -

> cl Record.c
>   Record

Now the doubt is, doesn't `typedef` check for symbols ? Does it work more like a `forward declaration` ?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"

typedef struct Record R;
struct Record
{
    int a;
};

int main()
{   
    R obj = {10};
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to put `typedef struct Record R;` under `struct Record ...`

Comment: @xhan - If I do it, it is a meaningful because symbol `Record` is found earlier. Thanks.

Comment: Your code ran fine under GCC (had to change getch to getchar) and VS2005. I suspect your findings are right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the syntactically proper way to declare a C struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698600/whats-the-syntactically-proper-way-to-declare-a-c-struct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always refer to undefined structures, which is a typical way to implement linked lists, after all.  They just have to be defined when you want to make use of their fields.
[This page](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40F_HTML/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_024.HTM) contains some details.

Answer (score 0):

C does not find the symbol Record because it is declared later on the code, like if you were trying to use a function you declare past on the code without defining its prototype.

You can also combine the two declarations, and then it becomes:

```
typedef struct Record
{
    int a;
} R;
```

It also works and, in my opinion, even better, not because it can be faster, but because it is smaller.

Comment: smaller is typedef struct { int a; } R;

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` must be used after its first parameter has been defined.

```
struct Record
{
    int a;
};
typedef struct Record R;
```

or

```
typedef struct Record
{
    int a;
} R;
```

---

If you need to use `struct Record` within the struct, just use `struct Record`:

```
typedef struct Record
{
    struct Record *next;
}
typedef struct Record R;
```