# typedef required in struct declaration

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to create an array of struct elements, as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct termstr{
double coeff;
double exp;
};

int main(){

termstr* lptr = malloc(sizeof(termstr)*5);

return 0;
}
```

When i compile this, i get errors as follows:

```
term.c: In function ‘main’:
term.c:11:1: error: unknown type name ‘termstr’
term.c:11:31: error: ‘termstr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

However, when i change my code to the following, it compiles as usual:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct termstr{
double coeff;
double exp;
}term;

int main(){

term* lptr = malloc(sizeof(term)*5);

return 0;
}
```

I've added typedef (with type name as term), changed the name of struct to termstr and am allocating memory with term* as the type of pointer.

Is typedef always required for such a situation i.e. for creating arrays of structs? If not, why was the first code giving errors? Is typedef also required to create and use a single instance of a struct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the syntactically proper way to declare a C struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698600/whats-the-syntactically-proper-way-to-declare-a-c-struct)

Comment: No, you dont need typedef. You could also do without, but you'll need to add struct keyword: `struct termstr *lptr = malloc(5 * sizeof *lptr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First type is not working because you have forgot `struct` keyword before `termstr`. Your data type is `struct termstr` but not just `termstr`. When you `typedef`, the resulting name is used as an alias for `struct termstr`.

Even you don't need to do that. Using `typedef` is better:

By the way don't forget to free the memory:

read [why to use typedef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)

Your working code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct termstr{
  double coeff;
  double exp;
};

int main(){

struct termstr* lptr = malloc(sizeof(struct termstr)*5);
free(lptr);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
struct termstr * lptr = malloc(sizeof(struct termstr)*5);
```

or even better:

```
struct termstr * lptr = malloc(sizeof(*lptr)*5);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, the name of the data type is "struct termstr", not just "termstr".

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
typedef struct termstr{
   double coeff;
   double exp;
} termstrStruct;
```

And then you can use only `termstrStruct` as the struct's name:

```
termstrStruct* lptr = malloc(sizeof(termstrStruct)*5);
```

It is not always required, you can simply write `struct termstr`.

Don't forget to `free` the allocated memory!

Comment: Although this is perfectly valid, I'd consider it code obfuscation naming different things the same.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know exactly what did he mean by this struct, but I edited it to have a different name.

Answer (score 1):

Typedef is a convenient way of shortening this:

```
struct termstr* lptr = (struct termstr*)malloc(sizeof(struct termstr)*5);
```

to this:

```
typedef struct termstr* term;
term* lptr = (term*)malloc(sizeof(term)*5);
```

Casting the malloc is also a good idea!

Comment: Casting the malloc is a terrible idea. IMO. (BTW: you'd need an extra asterix there)

Comment: Why casting `malloc()` in C is unnecessary and even more a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576

Comment: Huh, my profs always said casting was better style.  Well, you learn something new everyday!

Comment: General rule: when you have the choice to cast or not, casting is poor style. Casting means telling the compiler "no, you're wrong, I know better". If you don't *have* to tell the compiler this, *don't*; the compiler's job is to help you with its complaints.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the typename termstr on it's own you can use typedef:
    typedef struct {
      double a;
      double b;
    } termstr;

Answer (score 0):

In C you need to add the struct keyword as well, so either you use a typedef to link an alias with 'struct termstr' or you need to write something like

```
struct termstr* lptr = malloc(sizeof(struct termstr)*5);
```

In C++ however you can reference it as 'termstr' directly (read: the struct keyword isn't required there anymore).