# C struct declaration and initialization

Tags: c, struct

I have been following tutorials from the web on creating a struct and then initializing it in main(). From the tutorials I have followed, I have created my own example, which is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    int num;
};

main() {
    test structure;
}
```

However, this does not work:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:8: error: 'test' undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:8: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:8: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:8: error: expected ';' before 'structure'
```

But when I change:

```
test structure;
```

to:

```
struct test structure;
```

the code compiles. Why is this though? From the numerous examples I have looked at it seems that I shouldn't need the 'struct' before 'test structure'.

Thanks for your help/comments/answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [typedef required in struct declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124902/typedef-required-in-struct-declaration)

Comment: Are those C tutorials or C++ tutorials?

Comment: I would say this is a duplicate. My apologies, I tried searching for the answer before posting but I did not include the word "typedef" in my search so the link you have posted did not come up. Thank you.

Comment: `main()` returns `int`, too. Your tutorials seem not so good.

Comment: Compiles and runs without int for me; however, I am not arguing that it isn't needed.

Comment: The correctness of C code cannot be ascertained by compiling and running, C doesn't work like that.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my first comment, I wasn't arguing as to the "correctness" of the C code, I was simply saying that it compiles and runs without 'int'.

Comment: I know exactly what you were saying, and I was telling you that this fact is not relevant to my comment. The fact it compiles and runs for you tells you nothing about whether or not `main()` is required to return `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were reading C++ examples. In C the type of your structure is `struct test` not `test`.

Comment: Thank you! Will accept your answer as the correct answer shortly (currently have to wait 11 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

You can get around that by doing

```
typedef struct test_s 
{
    int num;
} test;
```