# Different syntax of structure in C

Tags: c, struct

What are the different syntax of c structure? How do decode this :

```
struct p {
    char a[1];
    int b;
    int *a;
    int value;
};
struct p q[] = {
    {"a",      0, &b, C},
    {"J",      0, &k, l}
};
```

I found a another discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698600/whats-the-syntactically-proper-way-to-declare-a-c-struct) but didn't encounter this type.

Comment: Here you are declaring `q` not `struct p`.

Comment: You are posting a struct initialization yet link to a post discussing various forms of struct declaration sytax. Those are different things, so it is unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: @Lundin: What is difference ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`q` is the array of structure of type `p`.

`p` has following elements:

1. char pointer
2. any type (int,char,short etc. even a pointer is possible)
3. pointer to any type
4. should be a constant

The syntax is actually initializing `q[0]` and `q[1]`

Comment: Is it equivalent to: struct p { }q[];  ?

Comment: @SHIVENDRAMISHRA It is almost same,only difference is that  `struct p { }q[];` does not have member initialization.

Comment: @Vagish Why `char*` and not simply `char` for the first element? There's nothing that recalls a pointer in the first element.

Comment: @boh `"a"` is a `string` NOT a `char`

Answer (score 1):

That is declaring an array called q of type struct p, it is not actually defining a struct at all. The {"a",      0, etc...}'s inside the initialization list are creating the structs that populate the first and second element of the array by defining values for the structs fields, and in doing so, creating instances of the struct on the stack.

struct p appears to contain a
char*,

an integer,

some other pointer

and something else(probably an integer).

Comment: Is it called C99 style ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I would assume it was new in C99. I am just going from what I can infer from the code you posted.