# Is the typedef-name optional in a typedef declaration?

Tags: c++, c, typedef

I was quite surprised when I saw the following code compile without errors or warnings in g++-4.2:

```
typedef enum test { one };
```

My assumption was that if you used the `typedef` keyword it would require an extra identifier as in:

```
typedef enum test { one } test;
```

As already mentioned, g++-4.2 accepts it without even a warning. Clang++ 3.0 warns "*warning: typedef requires a name*", similarly Comeau warns "*warning: declaration requires a typedef name*", and g++-4.6 informs: "*warning: 'typedef' was ignored in this declaration*".

I have not been able to identify where in the standard this is allowed, and I find it slightly confusing that two of the compilers warn that it is *required*, shouldn't it be an error if the typedef-name is *required* but not present?

**UPDATE**: I have checked in C with the same compilers. Clang and comeau yield the same output, gcc gives a warning: "*warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration*", which seems even more confusing.

**UPDATE**: I have checked removing the name of the enum and the results are the same:

```
typedef enum { one };
```

Similarly with a named struct:

```
typedef struct named { int x };
```

But not with an unnamed struct, in which case the code was rejected in g++ (4.2/4.6) with "*error: missing type-name in typedef-declaration*", gcc (4.2/4.6) gave a warning: "*warning: unnamed struct/union that defines no instances*", clang++ "*warning: declaration does not declare anything*", comeau "*error: declaration requires a typedef name*"

Comment: Interesting, VS2010 also accepts the code without any warning / error.

Comment: Isn't the syntax `typedef enum { one } test`?

Comment: yeah, i think it should be an error.

Comment: @Radu: That's the syntax for an unnamed enum, not what is being asked here.

Comment: This isn't really C++, is it?

Comment: @Xeo: C++ does not require the enum qualifier once it is has already been typedef'd.

Comment: @0A0D: And that makes it non-C++ in what way? I doesn't even require the enum qualifier if it hasn't been `typedef`'d.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is a degenerate syntax that is allowed but provides no benefit.  Most modern compilers can be provoked into emitting a warning about it; by default, they may not.  Without the typedef name, the keyword `typedef` is superfluous; in your example, it is completely equivalent to:

```
enum test { one };
```

Another place where it can occur is with a structure:

```
typedef struct SomeThing { int whatever; };
```

This is equivalent to:

```
struct SomeThing { int whatever; };
```

Note that `typedef` is officially (or syntactically) a 'storage class specifier', like `static`, `extern`, `auto` and `register`.

---

### C Standard

In ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (that's the C standard), we find:

> #### §6.7 Declarations
>
> **Syntax**
>
> *declaration*:
>
> *declaration-specifiers* *init-declarator-list*<sub>opt</sub>;
>
> *declaration-specifiers*:
>
> *storage-class-specifier* *declaration-specifiers*<sub>opt</sub>
>
> *type-specifier* *declaration-specifiers*<sub>opt</sub>
>
> *type-qualifier* *declaration-specifiers*<sub>opt</sub>
>
> *function-specifier* *declaration-specifiers*<sub>opt</sub>
>
> *init-declarator-list*:
>
> *init-declarator*
>
> *init-declarator-list* , *init-declarator*
>
> *init-declarator*:
>
> *declarator*
>
> *declarator* = *initializer*

And (as requested):

> #### §6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers
>
> **Syntax**
>
> storage-class-specifier:
>
> `typedef`
>
> `extern`
>
> `static`
>
> `auto`
>
> `register`

If you track through that syntax, there are a lot of degenerate possibilities, and what you showed is just one of the many.

---

### C++ Standard

It is possible that C++ has different rules.

In ISO/IEC 14882:1998 (the original C++ standard), we find in §7.1.1 'Storage class specifiers' that C++ does not treat `typedef` as a storage class; the list adds `mutable` and excludes `typedef`.  So, the grammatical specification of `typedef` in C++ is definitely different from the C specification.

> #### §7 Declarations

Declarations specify how names are to be interpreted. Declarations have the form

> declaration-seq:
>
> declaration
>
> declaration-seq declaration
>
> declaration:
>
> block-declaration
>
> function-definition
>
> template-declaration
>
> explicit-instantiation
>
> explicit-specialization
>
> linkage-specification
>
> namespace-definition
>
> block-declaration:
>
> simple-declaration
>
> asm-definition
>
> namespace-alias-definition
>
> using-declaration
>
> using-directive
>
> simple-declaration:
>
> decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> init-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub> ;
>
> ...
>
> ¶5 If the decl-specifier-seq
>   contains the `typedef` specifier, the declaration is called a `typedef` declaration and
>   the name of each `init-declarator`
>   is declared to be a typedef-name,
>   synonymous with its associated type
>   (7.1.3).
>
> #### §7.1 Specifiers [dcl.spec]
>
> The specifiers that can be used in a declaration are
>
> decl-specifier:
>
> storage-class-specifier
>
> type-specifier
>
> function-specifier
>
> `friend`
>
> `typedef`
>
> decl-specifier-seq:
>
> decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>
>
> decl-specifier
>
> #### §7.1.1 Storage class specifiers [dcl.stc]
>
> storage-class-specifier:
>
> `auto`
>
> `register`
>
> `static`
>
> `extern`
>
> `mutable`
>
> #### §7.1.2 Function specifiers [dcl.fct.spec]
>
> function-specifier:
>
> `inline`
>
> `virtual`
>
> `explicit`
>
> #### §7.1.3 The typedef specifier [dcl.typedef]
>
> Declarations containing the decl-specifier
>   `typedef` declare identifiers that can be used later for naming
>   fundamental (3.9.1) or compound (3.9.2) types. The `typedef` specifier shall not be used in a function-definition
>   (8.4), and it shall not be combined in a decl-specifier-seq
>   with any other kind of specifier except
>   a type-specifier.
>
> typedef-name:
>
> identifier
>
> ...
>
> In a given scope, a typedef specifier can be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that scope
>   to refer to the type to which it already refers. [Example:
>
> ```
> typedef struct s { /* ... */ } s;
> typedef int I;
> typedef int I;
> typedef I I;
> ```
>
> —end example]
>
> #### §7.1.4 The friend specifier [dcl.friend]
>
> The friend specifier is used to specify access to class members; see 11.4.
>
> #### §7.1.5 Type specifiers [dcl.type]
>
> type-specifier:
>
> simple-type-specifier
>
> class-specifier
>
> enum-specifier
>
> elaborated-type-specifier
>
> cv-qualifier

---

Since §7 ¶5 says that `typedef` names come from the *init-declarator* and the *init-declarator-list* is tagged '*opt*', I think that means that the `typedef` name can be omitted in C++, just as in C.

Comment: So it *was* in the C standard. Let me find that in the C++ one. Edit: Actually, in C++, the `typedef` is handled as an extra case. See §7.1(.1).

Comment: @Jonathan, does that mean that this syntax is valid in C and invalid in C++? At least from the name `decl-specifier` I'd deduce that this must be in the declaration of an identifier, and since there is none this would be invalid? (That some C++ compilers accept it is another thing.)

Comment: This does provide a solution to some of the questions that I had about the typedef so I am accepting it. But it does not explain why `typedef struct {};` is diagnosed in g++ as an error while `typedef enum {};` isn't (on the empty unnamed struct, gcc just warns, clang/clang++ warn, comeau rejects the code both in C and C++ mode...)

Comment: @David that appears to be a bug in GCC. it's only an error in C++ if the decl-specifier-seq does not introduce any names into the translation unit. It seems that GCC assumes that any enumeration has enumerators and will declare those as names. But for an empty enumeration, that assumption doesn't hold, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I could find was the following in the C++03 standard `§7.1.3 [dcl.typedef] p1`:

> *typedef-name:*
>
> - *identifier*
>
> A name declared with the `typedef` specifier becomes a *typedef-name*.

Notice the missing *<sub>opt</sub>* after *identifier*, which indicates, atleast to me, that an *identifier* is needed for the *typedef-name*. Strange that all tested compilers (silently) accept this.

---

**Edit**: After @Jonathan's answer, I found the following in the same standard as above:

> *decl-specifier*:
>
> - *storage-class-specifier*
> - *type-specifier*
> - *function-specifier*
> - `friend`
> - `typedef`

As can be seen, it provides an extra case for `typedef` and the list on *storage-class-specifiers* confirms this:

> storage-class-specifier:
>
> - `auto`
> - `register`
> - `static`
> - `extern`
> - `mutable`

So, we're just as clueless as before in the C++ case.

Comment: This is as far as I got, there is no optionality there, but I was not able to find where in the grammar *typedef-name* is used, in case that the optionality was marked there (something like *typedef type-specifier typedef-name_opt*

Comment: @David: Yeah, I can't find something like that too. :/ Maybe the C89 standard is more elaborate on this one.

Comment: Eh? Clang, Comeau and g++4.6 all warned. That means they didn't "silently accept" it. *If* it's an error then they diagnosed the error, the C++ standard only requires that conforming implementations diagnose ill-formed programs. It *doesn't* require that conforming implementations refuse to compile them, although neither does it define their behavior. It's perfectly legal for a conforming C++ compiler to use the C meaning of that syntax production, provided it warns.

Comment: @Steve: I put the "silently" in parens, to indicate that I meant only some of them.

Comment: ah, OK. Well then my tentative explanation is that g++ 4.2 was a bug, and for the others because they're all C compilers too under the covers, and because the C meaning is harmless, their authors considered it reasonable to use the C meaning. If you use `-Werror` then you don't have to fret about the difference between diagnosing and rejecting :-)

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like a C vs. C++ difference, to me. C++ implicitly typedefs structs and unions to their tags; so adding the typedef is superfluous, but not an error. I don't know if this works for enums as well.

The thing to do next is to see what variable definitions are permitted after these declarations.

```
enum test etest;
test etest2;
struct named snamed;
named snamed2;
```

Comment: This answer is unrelated to the question, which is specifically whether the *typedef-name* in the typedef is optional or not. Also, the use of `typedef` in C++ is not superfluous, as it affects the interpretation of the code, you can read more in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions/1675446#1675446) to an older question.