# Strange usage of typedef + enum

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the typedef-name optional in a typedef declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399898/is-the-typedef-name-optional-in-a-typedef-declaration)

I'm on Visual Studio 2008 and I saw this:

```
typedef enum testfoo
{
    enum1,
    enum2,
    enum3
};
```

Normally the C-style way of using typedef this way requires one additional piece (the name):

```
typedef enum testfoo
{
    enum1,
    enum2,
    enum3
} testfoo_name;
```

What is the former example doing? Strangely it compiles, but not sure what it's actually defining.

Comment: Short answer, the `typedef` is completely meaningless in the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference. The second creates an alias for the `enum` but the first doesn't. The `typedef` in the first example doesn't actually do anything. This gives me a warning in GCC so I suspect you can take it out.

In C, it's common to `typedef` structs and enums so as to avoid instantiating with the struct or enum name. For instance:

```
struct A {};

struct A a;
```

To shorten this, a `typedef` does the trick:

```
typedef struct {} A;
```

This is no longer necessary in C++ so I'm deriving my assumption of his misconception with this concept. Or maybe the author forgot to give it a name...

The same thing occurs when using classes or structs:

```
typedef struct A {}; // simply a class-declaration, generates a warning
```

Comment: @CarlNorum: If you're going to create a typedef (which isn't really necessary even in C), you might as well use the same identifier for the typedef name and the tag: `typedef enum testfoo { enum1, enum2, enum 3 } testfoo;` -- which the code in the question didn't do. In C, this lets you refer to the type either as `enum testfoo` or as `testfoo`. In C++ it does the same thing, except that it happens anyway even without the `typedef`.

Comment: @Keith - my comment is in reference to a previous version of this answer.  It doesn't really make sense anymore - I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is just a useless `typedef`.  I believe it's syntactically legal, but it doesn't provide a name for the type definition, so it's equivalent to:

```
enum testfoo { enum1, enum2, enum3 );
```

In C, this creates a type with the name `enum testfoo`; it's common (but not necessary) to use a typedef to allow the type to be referred to as just `testfoo`.

In C++, the type can be referred to either as `enum testfoo` or as `testfoo`, even without the typedef.

I suspect someone was confused about the rules, saw that the type can be referred to (in C++) as `testfoo`, and incorrectly assumed that this was because of the `typedef`.