# vect<myStruct*> var; access violation reading location

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2013, stdvector

I have the folowing structure defined

```
typedef struct NodeMulti{
    int key;
    vector<NodeMulti*> child;
};
```

in a function let's say I have:

```
NodeMulti* newNode = (NodeMulti*)malloc(sizeof(NodeMulti));
NodeMulti* anotherNode = (NodeMulti*)malloc(sizeof(NodeMulti));
newNode->child.push_back(anotherNode);
```

it does not work, any suggestions on how to fix it?
if i try changing the key value, it works; for ex:
 'newNode->key =...` works fine
thanks!

Comment: This is C++ not C, you should be using `new` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: You can remove the `typedef`, [it isn't doing anything](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6399898/3425536).

Comment: thanks, the 'new' operator did the trick :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ use `new`, not `malloc`.

`malloc` only allocates memory but will not call constructors. E.g. your `vector` is left uninitialized, thus trying to access it (e.g. `push_back`) invokes undefined behavior.

`new` both allocates memory and calls constructors, so your `vector` will be initialized using its default constructor, which creates an empty `vector`.

Also, in C++ you can declare a `struct` just like so:

```
struct NodeMulti { ... };
```

I.e. no need for the `typedef`. Also in your code you're not even assigning a name in the `typedef` declaration, so [it has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6399898/3425536).