# Does declaring struct Name make Name equivalent to struct Name?

Tags: c++, c, struct, typedef

I am a bit confused when using struct in c/c++. Traditionally, when I use `struct`, I usually use it as:

```
typedef struct Name{
    int a;
};

Name var;
```

Although it is considered a bad practice [from Linus](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/coding-style.html#typedefs), it's somehow common.

Yet, I wonder

```
struct Name{
    int a;
};
Name var;
```

Seems to serve the same purpose, is `typedef` really necessary?
In fact, shouldn't it be

```
struct Name{
    int a;
};
struct Name var;
```

Why is the `struct` from "Name" omitted? If it can always be omitted, does that mean `typedef struct` is totally useless?

Comment: This is why specifying languages properly is important. The second code block is C++, the others *would* work in both C and C++. They're different languages. The first one should also have a `Name` after the closing `}`, the `typedef` is incomplete there.

Comment: not sure what Linus would say to applying his guide to C++ :P. Please choose one language. The answers for C and C++ for this specific question will be very different. It seems like you refer to C

Comment: @Darth-CodeX - That's a misrepresentation. IIRC Linus said it's terrible for *kernel* development.

Comment: `typedef struct Name {int a;}` [is a useless `typedef`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6399898/509868): it doesn't define any new type (your compiler should emit a warning when it sees this). This code is equivalent to `struct Name {int a;}`. Using a useless `typedef` is a common error because "you must use `typedef`" is a common guideline, and a useless `typedef` looks like the most straightforward syntax, even though it does nothing.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I agree, forgot to edit that, `nothing can even come close to C when it comes to kernel dev`

Comment: Pick one language and delete the other tag. Better, since there are answers already, delete the question. If you still need clarification, post a new question with only one language tag. However, I recommend working completely through a primer or textbook or completing a class in the language before asking elementary questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You need `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error c++ compiler detected` / `#endif`

Comment: The `typedef struct Name { ... } Name;` construct in C is so common that when they made C++ they made that implicit. In C++ when you write `struct Name` or `class Name` is defines a type `Name` that you can use without `struct` or `class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For:

```
typedef struct Name{
    int a;
};

Name var;
```

The definition should be:

```
typedef struct Name{
    int a;
} Name;

Name var;
```

Otherwise you are not aliasing the type.

---

In C++ this doesn't make sense, when you declare `struct Name` you can already instantiate `Name` omitting the `struct` keyword, as you do in the second code snippet, which would not work for `C`. It behaves similarly to `class`, in this regard, you don't declare `class Name var;`, just `Name var;`.

In C I don't agree it's a bad practice, it's a user defined type, why would you always use `struct` if you can omit it, any programmer worthy of that name should be able to identify a user defined type, it's not rocket science. This though is opinion based. If it's bad practice we will need to revise the whole notion, not only in C++ but also C#, where `class` and `struct` keywords are always omitted when instantiating objects.

As for aliasing pointers, I completely agree, I do not like it one bit, though this can also be seen as opinion based.

So to answer your direct questions:

> *Seems to serve the same purpose, is `typedef` really necessary?*

For the purpose you describe in C yes, in C++ no.

> *Why is the `struct` from "Name" omitted?*

In C it cannot be ommited, unless you `typedef`ine it, in C++ not only it can, but it should, it's not needed at all.

> *If it can always be omitted, does that mean `typedef struct` is totally useless?*

As you can see, it's not useless.

Answer (score 1):

Always using `struct` keyword while initializing a variable could be lengthy (or whatever you think). That's why there's a `typedef` keyword (although it have many other uses too).

You can declare a struct with typedef like this:

```c
typedef struct{
    int a;
}var;
```

**or**

```c
struct Name{
    int a;
};

typedef struct Name var;
```

Then use it like:

```c
var my_age;
```

However, the above explanation covers only `C`, whereas in `C++` structs are similar to classes but their members are public by default.

So, in `C++` you can directly use the struct's name without typing `struct` keyword again n again

```cpp
struct Name {
    int a;
};

Name my_age;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, rules are different. The code you show is clearly C++, it wouldn’t compile in C.

With the following definitions:

```c
struct Foo {
    /*fields*/
};

typedef struct Bar {
    /*fields*/
} Baz;
```

in C, variable declarations `struct Foo var`, `struct Bar var`, `Baz var` are valid, but plain `Foo var` or `Bar var` are not. In C++ all such variable declarations are valid. Thus, C code would typically look like:

```c
struct Foo {
    /*fields*/
};

typedef struct {
    /*fields*/
} Baz;

struct Foo var1;
Baz var2;
```

while in C++, the typical form is:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    /*fields*/
};

Foo var;
```

UPD: technically, that’s because in `struct Foo {...`, in C type name is `struct Foo`; while in C++ the name is simply `Foo`, and `struct` is only needed to declare the type, not to use it.