# struct keyword in function parameter, and const-correctness

Tags: c++, c, const-correctness

I have an opaque type in my library defined as:

```
typedef struct MyOpaqueType* MyType;  // easier to type for client code
```

I can't pass a pointer-to-const struct around using the typedef, so some functions look like:

```
void UsePointerToConst ( const struct MyOpaqueType * )
```

instead of:

```
void UserPointerToConst( const MyType ) // can't use, is really constant pointer
```

So, given this, I have two questions:
Is the struct keyword in the parameter list only necessary in C?
Is there a better way to do this?  Should I create a typedef such as:

```
typedef const struct MyOpaqueType* ConstantMyType; ?
```

Comment: Win32 does exactly that: `LPSTR` (pointer to null-terminated string) vs `LPCSTR` (pointer to `const` null-terminated string), etc etc.

Comment: The second typedef is a reasonable solution to the problem.

Comment: <flamebait>The fact that Win32 does it this way is no reason for anyone to copy its bad habits.</flamebait>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the struct keyword in the parameter list only necessary in C?

<s>Yes.</s> See Jens Gustedt's answer.

> Is there a better way to do this?

Just `typedef` the struct, not the pointer. This is better because

- you only need one `typedef` instead of one for each of {`MyOpaqueType`, `MyOpaqueType *`, `MyOpaqueType const *`, `MyOpaqueType *const` and `MyOpaqueType const *const`} and all variants involving `restrict` (which doesn't exist in C++),
- it's clear to the user that pointer semantics apply, i.e., passing the datatype around is really a matter of pointer copying (no performance worries), users are less likely to forget cleaning up after use, C++ users may use smart pointers, and
- it's a common C convention (think `FILE *`).

There's also no danger; when someone forgets the `*`, they get a compiler error.

Comment: @Cat It exists, but is incomplete. You can still typedef it.

Comment: Yes, but hiding the notion that this opaque handle is a pointer is something I'd like to keep.  typedef struct MyOpaqueType* MyType is a library idiom that this code has used for years.  I might not understand what you're getting at, though.

Comment: @Cat It's a common C idiom. C++ is a bit different - the struct keyword introduces a new type name, for example. You could use two typedefs (for const and non-const), but idiomatic C++ would probably do it as I suggest in my answer.

Comment: @Cat: I was in a hurry when I typed this answer. Expanded it with why pointer `typedef`'s are a bad idea for your problem.

Comment: +1 for recommending against hiding that the target of the `typedef` is a pointer.

Comment: I like the reminder about the information conveyed when using obvious pointer semantics.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ a `typedef` of the same name as a `struct` is assumed as long as there is no other identifier with that name. So something like a function `stat` that receives a `struct stat*` as an argument:

```
int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

is even allowed in C++. (This is a real world example.)

So you are always better of with forward declarations like

```
typedef struct toto toto;
```

which reserves the token `toto` in the identifier and in the struct name space. Then you can have your function interface declared for C and C++. But don't forget the `extern "C"` if you want to access it from C, too.

See also: [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions/1675446#1675446) and [struct tags are not identifiers in C++](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/struct-tags-are-not-identifiers-in-c/).

Comment: To be precise, the identifiers of user defined types and the rest of identifiers are kept separate in C++ in the same way as in C, **but**, when looking up an identifier in a scope, if the identifier is not located in the global identifier space, then it is also searched in the user defined types identifier space... kind of subtle difference.

Comment: @David, yes, it even allows more absurd things as first using the bare word as a referring to the `struct` and then defining a variable afterwards. C++ is a very context sensitive language, but we knew that already, don't we.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the typedef at all in C++. Just use a forward declaration:

```
struct MyType;
```

Then pass around `MyType const *`, `MyType *`, `MyType const &` etc as and when required.

Comment: I don't want to ever pass around anything but a pointer the structure, because the structure does not exist, and just exists for type safety.

Comment: @Cat It most definitely exists; you declared it so it exists. You don't ever have to define it for the above to work. Try it!

Comment: Even if you never define what that structure looks like, you can still use a forward declaration like this to allow you to create pointers to a structure with that name.  Just don't try to de-reference them if you haven't defined the structure...

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Sorry, I read your comment too quickly.  Won't C code parameters have to be written as PublicFunction(struct MyType* t)?  I think PF(MyType t) is easier to read.

Comment: @Cat Write `typedef struct MyType MyType;` if you need it to work in both C and C++. `PF(MyType * t)` is both easy to read and explicit about what is happening.