# Why are some local type declarations prefixed with 'struct' in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I often see C++ code like this:

```
void foo()
{
  struct sockaddr* from;
  // ...
}
```

Why is the `struct` specifier needed? Does it actually do anything? The compiler can already know that `sockaddr` is declared as a struct, so I wonder why this is useful or necessary.

I've tried removing it in the past and haven't noticed a difference in behaviour, but I'm not confident it's safe to remove.

Similarly, what's the difference between these two?

```
sizeof(struct sockaddr)
sizeof(sockaddr)
```

Comment: Does not it come from old C years?

Comment: @Naszta "Does it not come from old C years?" - Sorry

Comment: @Naszta, I have wondered as much. If so, why would it be necessary in C but not in C++?

Comment: @DrewNoakes: [FYI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language))

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1675446/36565) answer to a related question.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a coding "style", this is most likely a heritage of C, where the keyword is necessary.

In C++ this is not needed in most situations, although it is used sometimes to force the compiler to resolve a name to the name of a type rather than the name of some other entity (like a variable, as in the following example):

```
struct x
{
};

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    struct x* pX = nullptr; // Would give a compiler error without struct
}
```

Personally, I do not consider good style having a variable, or a function with the same name as a type, and I prefer avoiding having to use the `struct` keyword for this purpose at all, but the language allows it.

Comment: In your code example, could you also clarify the type using the `typename` keyword?

Comment: @DrewNoakes: No, `typename` cannot be used in this context. Basically `typename` can only be used inside templates.

Answer (score 4):

This syntax comes from C, where it's obligatory.
In C++ there is only one needed usage of this syntax

n3376 9.1/2

> A class declaration introduces the class name into the scope where it is declared and hides any class, variable,
> function, or other declaration of that name in an enclosing scope (3.3). If a class name is declared in a scope
> where a variable, function, or enumerator of the same name is also declared, then when both declarations
> are in scope, the class can be referred to only using an elaborated-type-specifier
>
> ```
> struct stat {
> // ...
> };
> stat gstat; // use plain stat to
> // define variable
> int stat(struct stat*); // redeclare stat as function
> void f() {
> struct stat* ps; // struct prefix needed
> // to name struct stat
> stat(ps); // call stat()
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Code such as this comes directly from C (most likely via copy & paste), where the `struct` keyword is required before the name of any type that is defined as a struct (unless you add the appropriate `typedef` statement).  Using `struct` in this way is still supported in C++ for backwards compatibility, but because `struct foo { ... };` in C++ automatically adds `foo` as a type name, it is (usually) safe to refer to the type afterwards as just `foo`.

Comment: Yes I usually see this in code that's using C APIs, such as the socket example in my original question. Makes sense, and I'll now feel more confident to strip it out most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You are largely correct; in C++ the struct keyword is hardly ever relevant in declaring a variable.

More than you ever wanted to know about this: [using struct keyword in variable declaration in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729646/using-struct-keyword-in-variable-declaration-in-c)