# Pointer Syntax C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Regarding binary trees - I had seen the following code as part of the solution for a problem:

```
struct Node
{
    int key;
    struct Node *left, *right;
};
```

My question is what does "struct Node *left, *right" mean given it is defined w/in the body of the first struct Node definition. Also if this is C++ why would you use struct instead of just class/object here?

Comment: `struct` and `class` are essentially the same thing in C++. The only difference is that `struct` members are `public` by default and `class` members are `private` by default. For that reason it is common to use `class` anytime you want encapsulation, and `struct` when you merely want to gather together related public data members e.g. [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7729819/1236397

Comment: Why couldn't you just write "Node *left, *right" instead of "struct Node *left, *right"

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939: You can, as long as you're writing C++ and not C.

Comment: Sorry - can you explain that a little more - i.e. what advancement does C++ have that makes it not ok to do that for C?

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939 nothing "advanced", really; just a different (but similar) language. C++ is more of a high level language; think of C as one step up from machine code. You have to be pretty specific with C; C++ allows you to do a lot more at the expense of simplicity and understandability.

Comment: Thanks! Last question - I could look this up but I'd just get your take on it. If Javascript doesn't have pointers, how would they handle implementing a binary search tree (or something like the above snippet of code)?

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939 with pointers in the background. In JS, pointers are not exposed in the language, but object have reference semantics meaning that a practical implementation will use pointers in the background. (JavaScript engines are almost universally written in C or C++.)

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939 as to your question "why do we need the struct keyword in C but not in C++": it's a purely syntactic thing. C++'s grammar allows the omission of struct, C's doesn't. It has nothing to do with how "advanced" each language is. (C is just as "advanced" as C++. It takes a lifetime to master. It's just not as complex as C++.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ (and especially C), types are usually always represented by their construct.

For instance,

```
enum Foo { ... };
void doSomethingWithAFoo(enum Foo f);

struct Bar { ... };
void doSomethingWithABar(struct Bar bar);
```

While this is *required* in C, it is not in C++. In C, it is achieved by using a `typedef`.

```
typedef struct { ... } Foo; // Can now be referenced with just `Foo`
```

---

However, there is a particular part of the spec that states that struct types cannot have instance of themselves inside of them (more specifically it states types cannot refer to themselves before they're fully declared).

Except in pointer form. This is because pointers are known sizes at the beginning of compilation, whereas structures are only known after they are declared.

---

Since `struct`s pre-date C++ (only by a little) and have been present since ANSI C (C89) and before in most major compilers, they are also present in C++ (since ANSI C can be compiled gracefully in compliant C++ compilers).

However, C++ adds the concept of classes, which *don't* exist in C. As others have mentioned, classes and structs are similar in that they both holds members. In C++, structs can have methods just like classes - obviously this is not the case in C.

The only difference as far as I'm aware is the visibility; `struct`s default to public and `class`es default to private. C does not have the notion of visibility.

Comment: I explain that; you're more than likely working with code that is actually C. It just happens to work with your C++ compiler.

Comment: Interesting, so it is in pointer form bc it is of type struct and its recursive (i.e. "struct Node *left, *right" instead of "struct Node left, right")?

Comment: Correct. Think about it; if the struct had to allocate space for itself, and then a copy of itself, those copies of themselves would also have to allocate space for more copies, and so on. It'd be never ending.

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939: If you wrote `Node left, right;` (without the pointers), then each `Node` would contain two Nodes.  How much memory, then, would a Node require?

Comment: C structs have existed since the 1970s - with K&R C.   It is not just "certain compilers" that supported them.

Comment: @Peter I know about friends that have talked about unofficial C compilers before ANSI standards were in place that didn't support structs and had other mechanisms for structured data. I'll clarify wording.

Comment: If you check, you'll find those compilers were of subsets of C.   K&R  (Kernighan and Ritchie) designed the original C with struct types.   That didn't stop some vendors producing stripped down versions that only implemented a subset of the language.   Similarly, there are some compilers now that only support a subset of ISO C.

Comment: @Peter I know who K&R are and what they did ;) Subsets of C or not, they were still considered C compilers in the day.

Answer (score 1):

Means exactly what it looks like.  A recursive declaration just means a Node struct had two fields that are pointers to other Nodes.

I've read that the main difference between structs and classes in C++ is the default permissions (structs are all public by default).  Slightly simpler, especially since inheriting is unlikely.

Comment: Why couldn't you just write "Node *left, *right" instead of "struct Node *left, *right"?

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `struct Node *left, *right;` within the definition of `struct Node` is that each instance of `struct Node` contains members (`left` and `right`) that point to other `struct Node`s.

It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that, whenever a `struct Node` is created, that those members are initialised appropriately.   They may be set to `NULL` (indicating they don't point at any object) or to the address of another `struct Node`.

In C++, initialisation of `left` and `right` will often be done in a constructor.  C doesn't have that feature so, every time some C code creates a `struct Node`, it will typically have to explicitly initialise the left and right members.

The code you have shown is really C, although it will be accepted by a C++ compiler.   C++ allows the declaration `struct Node *left, *right;` to omit the `struct` keyword.  C does not.

In C++, a `struct` and a `class` are the same thing - the difference is accessibility of members:  C++ `struct` members are `public` and `class` members are `private` by default.   C++ `struct`s (and `class`es) are able to do numerous other things that C `struct`s cannot.