# Is the use of `struct` well-defined in c++ function signatures?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This question is similar to, but more specific than, this other question:

[using struct keyword in variable declaration in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7729646/391161).

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y;
};

Foo getFoo() {
    Foo foo;
    return foo;
}

int main(){
    getFoo();
}
```

The above program compiles with `g++` but not `gcc`.

We can modify the program as follows to make it compile with both `gcc` and `g++`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Foo getFoo() {
    struct Foo foo;
    return foo;
}

int main(){
    getFoo();
}
```

Is this use of the `struct` keyword guaranteed by the standard to be **well-defined** in C++?

Comment: Another way to write code that compiles in both compilers is to start with code similar to the first example and just add a `typedef` for the struct type: `typedef struct Foo Foo;` then you don't have to use `struct Foo` everywhere.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Is the statement `typedef struct Foo Foo;` also well-defined in C++ for the same reason as the given answer?

Comment: I don't know. But typedefing a struct type is common practice in C. And you can wrap the typedef inside of `#ifndef __cplusplus` to skip it in C++, if you want`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. That's known as an [*elaborated-type-specifier*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier).