# What does this mean: "class DATA_C data_container"

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and while I'm reviewing someone else's code, I ran into an expression I don't understand.

In the header file I have a normal class definition:

```
//in data.hpp
class DATA_C : public QThread
{
   Q_OBJECT
   // the rest of class definition...
}
```

A snippet of the source file:

```
//in data.cpp
class DATA_C data_container;
```

I can understand "DATA_C data", which is a declaration; but what is "class DATA_C data_container"? What does it do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I suspect it's probably something to do with C, and is maybe answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729646/using-struct-keyword-in-variable-declaration-in-c

Comment: you could point out where you found that code

Comment: AFAIK，When instantiating a class object, you can use the Class keyword or not use it.

Comment: @eyllanesc this piece of code was written by one of my colleagues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context tt has exactly the same meaning as `DATA_C data_container;`.  In many contexts you can optionally use the term `class X` , if it would have been valid to just use `X`.

In general you can use `class X` when `X` has not been defined yet and it declares the class (but doesn't define it). But `class DATA_C data_container;` would not be allowed if `DATA_C` had not been previously defined, because you cannot instantiate an object of incomplete type.