# Some questions about struct namespace in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to understand [this answer - typedef struct vs struct definitions [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1675446/7813604):

> (Line 3): *["] In the first line you are defining the identifier S within the **struct name space** (**not in the C++ sense**). [."]*

1. It seems like for `struct X {...};`, the `{...}` is like an adjective for `X`, and `X {...}` is thrown into something called struct-namespace, how many struct-namespace are there in a program? Is there only one specified by `struct`?
2. It seems like in C/C++ struct and class are [almost the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54596/7813604) So in C++ struct and class are both in class-namespace?

Comment: A c++ struct is simply a class that defaults to public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 (for C): there is one namespace for all structure tags. You can have as many **different** tags as you want, even if the same name is used in other namespaces.

Each structure on its own is its own namespace (<s>there are "infinite" struct namespaces</s>).

```
// You can have
struct foo { int var; }
struct bar { double var; }
struct baz { int var; }
struct qux { int var; }
// with no conflict between all the `var`
```

Comment: So each different `X` is a namespace?

Comment: sort of, if you have a `struct one`, `one` is an identifier belonging to the struct namespace. `one` can also be one or more identifier(s) in other namespaces.

Comment: OK, so `struct {...} one, two, three;` only one namespaces and three identifiers for it? And is that in this case the struct is anonymous?

Comment: still not quite right. in `struct {...} one, two, three;` there is no identifier for the struct namespace: it's a struct without a tag (an anonymous struct, using no namespace). The identifiers `one`, `two`, and `three` belong to the regular namespace.

Comment: See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7729772/25324) to an older question.

Comment: "struct tag names" in your link the same as "identifier belonging to the struct namespace" in your first comment above?

Comment: Yes, the same meaning :)

Comment: "Each structure on its own is its own namespace", you mean those `{...}` following "different tags" are themselves namespaces?

Comment: Yes, in the example in my answer as well as the global namespace, the label namespace, the struct/tag/enum namespace, there is the `struct foo` namespace, the `struct bar` namespace, ... Without context, you can't say what `var` is. Context is the namespace

Comment: Don't worry, I upvoted your answer, I'm reading your link and thinking about which part I'm still confused. I'll give you another one after I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [C99 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

**6.2.3**

> 6.2.3  Name spaces of identifiers
>
> If  more  than  one  declaration  of  a  particular  identifier  is  visible  at  any point  in  a translation  unit,  the  syntactic  context  disambiguates  uses  that  refer  to  different  entities. Thus, there are separate *namespaces*
>   for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> —label names
>   (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
>
> —the
>   tags
>   of  structures,  unions,  and  enumerations  (disambiguated  by  following  any
>   of the keywords
>   struct
>   ,
>   union
>   ,or
>   enum
>   );
>
> —the
>   members
>   of  structures  or  unions;  each  structure  or  union  has  a  separate  name
>   space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the
>   member via the
>   .
>   or
>   ->
>   operator);
>
> —all other identifiers, called
>   ordinary identifiers
>   (declared in ordinary declarators or as
>   enumeration constants).

In other words, if you have `struct S`, then `S` is in the struct namespace, whereas if you have `int S` as well, then it's in the namespace of ordinary identifiers.

This is not the case for C++