# writing struct code that works both in C and in C++

Tags: c++, c, struct, compatibility, typedef

I am aware of two possible ways to define and use `struct`s:

```
#1 
struct person
{
    char name[32];
    int age;
};

struct person dmr = {"Dennis Ritchie", 70};

#2
typedef struct
{
    char name[32];
    int age;
} person;

person dmr = {"Dennis Ritchie", 70};
```

The interesting property of the first way is that both the type and the variable can have the same name:

```
struct person person = {"Sam Persson", 50};
```

Is that idiomatic in C? Is it guaranteed to work in C++? Or are there corner cases I should be aware of?

Note that I am not interested in pure C++ answers (e.g. "use `std::string` instead of `char[32]`"). This is a question about C/C++ compatibility.

Comment: I would not call that "interesting property" it is rather obscuring property. It is better to keep type names starting from upper case - for distinguishing type and variable names.

Comment: I have marked this as duplicate of [typedef struct vs struct definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions). Technically you can consider that it is not (the other question deals only with C) but the semantics are the same in C++ with the single difference that lookup will also find symbols in the user-defined identifier space if it does not find them in the global identifier space. That is also treated in the accepted answer (that contains bits of c++)

Comment: Also, they are **not** two ways of defining a `struct`, there is a single way of defining a `struct` (which can have or not a name), and there are `typedef`s (which can be applied to a named or unnamed type), but they are not two ways of defining a `struct` at any rate. And you are missing 3), combining both: `typedef struct type {} type;` for what it's worth (which is the idiomatic C way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct person person = {"Sam Persson", 50};
```

It is not idiomatic to use the same identifier for a type and a variable. In Unix, it is typical to use an abbreviated version for the variable name, e.g: `struct stat st`, `struct timeval tv`, ... the same way `fd` is a typical name for a file descriptor variable.

Answer (score 3):

`struct` are compatible between C & C++ only when they are [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure)-s.

I tend to code something like:

```
struct person_st { char name[32]; int age; };
typedef struct person_st Person_t;
```

Comment: So what are non-POD `struct` of C?

Comment: @xantos, `class`es! But instead of `class` you write `struct` and members are `public` by default as opposed to `private` in `class`es

Comment: @Shahbaz: There are no classes in C. I guess that's what xanatos meant.

Comment: @FredOverflow, ah yes, but the answer says PODs, not PODs in C! So I just assumed xantos means non-PODs in general.

Answer (score 2):

I declare them to have the same name in both the struct tag and global identifier namespaces:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct person
{
    char name[32];
    int age;
} person;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In use, that requires no use of the struct tag in both C and C++ translations:

```
person dmr = {"Dennis Ritchie", 70};
```

If you prefer the struct tag in some places, you could also use it that way.

The obvious benefit is that the type may be referred to by either identifier in both namespaces, regardless of language.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would be completely correct in standard C++, but I tested with `g++ -pedantic -Wall` and got no errors or warnings (note that this doesn't necessarily mean it's completely standard. g++, even with -pedantic, doesn't go through the trouble of giving warning for all non standard code.) (Does someone know the c++ spec well enough to comment on whether it is actually standard or not?)

The thing with writing:

```
struct person person = {...};
```

is that in C++, `person` both refers to the variable and to the type. In C, this wasn't a problem simply because `person` is not the type (`struct person` is). Although from the context, with the few tests I wrote with g++, the compiler had no problem understanding when I am asking for the variable and when for the type, I do think it might get confused at some point. One confusing thing that I discovered is that if you have:

```
struct person *person = ...;
```

then `sizeof(person)` returns the size of the variable, while to get the size of the type, you should write `sizeof(struct person)` which I can assure you, no c++ coder would remember to write the `stuct`.

It is best to avoid all kinds of confusion. I usually do this for code that could be used both in C and C++:

```
typedef struct person
{
    ...
} person;
```

Giving a name to the struct that is being `typedef`ed allows the programmer to use either `person` or `struct person`. So, a bit of flexibility (not to mention you don't have to change already written code after `typedef`ing the `struct`.

Comment: For the `sizeof` example. see the C++ standard §9.1 ¶2 _If a class name is declared in a scope where a variable, function, or enumerator of the same name is also declared, then when both declarations are in scope, the class can be referred to only using an elaborated-type-specifier_

Comment: No, in C++ for your first example `person` would refer to the variable.