# Different types of Struct

Tags: c, struct

I know the diff between struct and struct with typedef keyword in front. The reference is this: [typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

```
struct myStruct{
    int one;
    int two;
};
```

vs

```
typedef struct{
    int one;
    int two;
}myStruct;
```

But what is the diff between this two types:

```
struct point {
   int x;
   int y;
};
```

vs

```
struct point {
   int x;
   int y;
} my_point;
```

One more:

```
    typedef struct set_t{    
      int count;
      void **values;
   } *SetRef;
```

what is this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct point { int x; int y; };
```

This declares a new type `struct point` with two `int` members `x` and `y`.

```
struct point { int x; int y; } my_point;
```

This also declares a new type `struct point` with two `int` members `x` and `y` and this  declares an object `my_point` of type `struct point`.

Answer (score 2):

`my_point` is a variable of type `struct point`.

Answer (score 1):

The first declares a `struct` type, while the second one declares both the type and an instance `my_point`. In other words, `my_point` is not a type, but rather an actual `struct point` instance.

Answer (score 1):

In the second, you also define a varibale (named `my_point`) from the type `struct point`.

Answer (score 1):

The first one only declares the structure. You will have to use it later to create an object of it later.
The second one declares the structure and a object of it at the same time.