# c++ static method with struct parametrs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, struct, compiler-errors, static-methods

i have this problem...

i have a my struct:

```
typedef struct Mystruct{
  float a;
  float b;
}
```

and a static method:

```
float static MyStaticMethod(MyStruct a, MyStruct b);
```

when i call this method:

```
Mystruct s;
s.a = 1;
s.b = 2;

Mystruct t;
t.a = 1;
t.b = 2;

MyClass.MyStaticMethod(s,t);
```

i have this error at compile time:

```
Error   51  error C2228: left of '.MyStaticMethod' must have class/struct/union

Error   50  error C2275: 'MyClass' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

Comment: The use of `typedef` in the definition of `Mystruct` is useless. I would recommend that you remove it, but if you really need the *small* difference that it makes in C++, you need to provide a name for the typedef `typedef struct MyStruct {..} MyStruct;`. Again, I would just drop it. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1675446/36565), note that even if the main focus is C, the answer also deals with C++

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call it using a scope resolution operator:

```
MyClass::MyStaticMethod(s,t);
       ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

apart from using "MyClass::MyStaticMethod(s,t);", you could also call the static method on an instance:

```
MyClass instance;
instance.MyStaticMethod(s,t);
```

and it should read:

```
typedef struct {
  float a;
  float b;
} Mystruct;
```

(the new typename comes last)

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `static` is *overloaded* in the C++ language (i.e. it has multiple meanings). In the code that you presented:

```
struct MyStruct {
};
static float MyStaticFunction( MyStruct, MyStruct );
```

the meaning of `static` is *internal linkage* (i.e. the symbol will not be usable outside of the current translation unit. If this is present in a header, then each including translation unit will get it's own copy of the function. In this case, usage is that of a free function:

```
MyStruct a,b;
float f = MyStaticFunction( a, b );
```

It seems from the attempt to use it that what you meant was using `static` in this alternate scenario:

```
struct MyStruct {
   static float MyStaticFunction( MyStruct, MyStruct );
};
```

where it has a different meaning: *the member belongs to the class, not to a particular instance*. In this case, the function can be called in one of two ways, the most common one is:

```
MyStruct a,b;
float f = MyStruct::MyStaticFunction( a, b );
```

even though the language also allows (I would not recommend using it, it might be confusing):

```
float f a.MyStaticFunction(a,b);
```

Where the confusion arises because it looks like calling a *member* function on `a`, rather than calling a *static member* function on the class.