# What's the aim of typedef a former name?

Tags: c, typedef

Such as:

```
typedef struct _cairo_clip cairo_clip_t;
```

Why not directly use `_cairo_clip`? See numerous similar definitions in some code.

Comment: If I changed your post off from your initial question, please, edit it back.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions

Comment: FYI on the struct _cairo_clip.  The prefix _ would indicate that the author wants to somehow hide or "privatize" the name of the structure.  This is poor form IMHO.  There is no reason you can't type "struct cairo_clip" when you want to refer to the type of "struct cairo_clip".  Most of the time you see this from people coming from other languages to C.  They think the extra typing is somehow bad.  C is a simple language.  Writing struct cairo_clip is not bad form.  Other than the abstraction that Mankarse mentions, there isn't much benefit.  Also some would say the leading _ and _t are bad.

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind `typedef` is to let you skip the `struct` keyword. Unlike C++, C does not let you do this:

```
struct _cairo_clip {
    int a;
    float b;
};
_cairo_clip cc;        // Not allowed
struct _cairo_clip cc; // Allowed, but requires a keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to directly use `_cairo_clip`, you would need to call it `struct _cairo_clip`.

`struct _cairo_clip` is more verbose than `cairo_clip_t`.

Using a typedef also provides some abstraction, because it means that `cairo_clip_t` can be implemented as either a built-in type or as implemented as a `struct`, without causing a change in the syntax of the client code.