# Having a hard time figuring out how pointers to structs works in binary trees

Tags: pointers, struct, binary-search-tree

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct              //create a pointer structure
{
int data;
struct node *left;
struct node *right;
} node;

node *insert(node *root, int x);

//Insert Function
node *insert(node *root, int x)    //Line 53        
{    
    if(!root)
    {
        root = new_node(x);
        return root;
    }

    if (root->data > x)
    {
        root->left = insert(root->left, x);   //Line 63
    }

    else 
    {
        root->right = insert(root->right, x);  // Line 68
    }

    return root;
}
```

> I get the following errors while compiling:
>
> : In function ‘insert’:
>
> :63:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘insert’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>
> :53:7: note: expected ‘struct node *’ but argument is of type ‘struct node *’
>
> :63:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>
> :68:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘insert’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>
> :53:7: note: expected ‘struct node *’ but argument is of type ‘struct node *’
>
> :68:15: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

1. Why is the 1st argument in my insert function incompatible with what I am passing into it?
2. How do you assign a pointer to a 'struct pointer'?

Answer (score 0):

Change the struct definition to

```
struct node             //create a pointer structure
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
```

and the function prototype to

```
struct node *insert(struct node *root, int x);
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two styles of declaration?

Comment: A long topic [struct vs typedef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

Comment: That helped a bunch! I don't think the 'shorthand' definition is the way for me. The concept of pointers and BST's are still a little fuzzy. Are there any articles that you could recommend that helped you?