# Sqlite3 struct not resolved in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm kind of new to c/c++ within Eclipse, trying to program some sqlite routines for MATLAB, using the sqlite amalgamation.

I'm having the issue, that eclipse seems to be missing something around the basic `sqlite3` type.
I'm getting 'invalid arguments' errors on all functions taking a `sqlite3*` as input.

E.g. on `sqlite3_close` I'm getting

```
Invalid arguments
Candidates are: int sqlite3_close(*)
```

while the proper prototype is

```
int sqlite3_close(sqlite3*)
```

The same issue occurs with all `sqlite3_stmt` types.
I've included `sqlite3.h`, it's in the same directory  and, last but not least, the code compiles and runs just fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

From the sqlite3 code, line 12450

```
** The "sqlite3_stmt" structure pointer that is returned by sqlite3_prepare()
** is really a pointer to an instance of this structure.


 struct Vdbe {
    /*struct definition*/
}
```

That is, sqlite3_stmt is a [forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions?rq=1) that prevents the user to create a sqlite3_stmt structure but by using the sqlite3 functions.

In order to have Eclipse CDT recognize sqlite3_stmt you could add it as a symbol in your Eclipse project properties if you're not using it to compile.

Since I'm not, what I have is define sqlite3_stmt as Vdbe.