# Why use different a different tag and typedef for a struct?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

In C code, I've seen the following:

```
typedef struct SomeStructTag {
    // struct members
} SomeStruct;
```

I'm not clear on why this is any different from:

```
typedef struct SomeStruct {
    // struct members
} SomeStruct;
```

What's the point of using a particular name for the type and `typedef`ing it to a different type name?

Comment: Makes it a little easier to tell them apart at first glance?! Also some companies have naming conventions

Comment: Tagging this question with both C and C++ is odd.  In C there is a very good reason for the typedef.  In C++ you would just write `struct whatever`

Comment: A lot of people like having the same name. It solves some issues that different names could cause (which you can find in some of the related questions to the right).

Comment: Not the same question but related and thus contains good answers you might want to read through (in particular David's): http://stackoverflow.com/q/1675351/592323

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In most cases, one could use the same name for both purposes without any problem.  The practice of people using different names in code probably stems from the days before ANSI standardization, when there were a lot of compilers that accepted mostly-compatible dialects of something resembling C.  Some constructs and features would work on almost any compiler, others would work on most (but fail on a significant number), and others would only work on a few.  Although the standard has for many years clearly mandated that there are different namespaces for types, structure tags, and for the members of each individual structure, some compilers from the early days didn't recognize all those namespaces as distinct, a fair amount of code was written which was supposed to work even with such compilers, and people tend to write code which resembles other code they've seen.

I think the strongest objection to using the same identifier given today's rules would be the principle that distinct identifiers should look distinct, and one should generally avoid using two semantically-equivalent identifiers for a given purpose.  It's fine to use two distinct identifiers for some purpose if there's some clear semantic distinction between them (e.g. "the fastest type that's at least 32 bits" versus an "exactly 32 bits" type), but it's not good to have code use two different identifiers for the same purpose essentially at random.  If one declares `typedef struct FOO {...} FOO;`, then `struct FOO` and `FOO` will be distinct identifiers that look as though they should be interchangeable.  If there are particular cases where one is supposed to use one or the other and the names are distinct, then typing `struct` where one shouldn't, or vice versa, will cause a compilation error.  If the names match, things would compile and there would be no warning that the usage of the name wasn't consistent with its usage elsewhere.

Incidentally, although struct tags are globally available, there often isn't any need to use any tag more than once.  Even if a struct is supposed to contain self-referential pointers, one may, in ANSI C, declare it:

```
typedef struct NODE_S NODE;
struct NODE_S {
  NODE *parent,*left,*right;
};
```

without having to refer to the type as `struct NODE_S` anywhere except the particular line declaring the typedef name.  Everywhere else, one may instead simply use the typedef name directly.

Comment: @supercat So "struct FOO" versus just "FOO" is not distinct enough? I don't know. There are some context-specific aspects to all programming languages. I mean there are 3 _very_ different meanings of an asterisk (declaring a pointer variable, dereferencing a pointer variable, multiplying two values, which could be floating point or integer multiplication). When exactly is it unclear if "FOO" is a tag or a type?

Comment: Ignoring the forward-declaration issue, I'm trying to decide between: completely anonymous, same tag and type name, some prefix/suffix but otherwise the same. I don't like how PREFast had warnings "unnamed struct 123" when I kept it anonymous. I don't like how Doxygen seems to prefer the tag name over the type name when they are different.

Comment: @RichJahn: Consider `typedef struct foo { int x; } foo; int bar; ... void test(void) { int foo; foo *bar; bar = 0; }`, the `test` function would be valid as written, or with the `foo *bar` statement replaced with a `struct foo *bar;` declaration, but the meanings would be different with and without the word `struct`.

Answer (score 9):

There is one functional reason for using a different tag between the typedef and the struct.  This is when you're doing a linked list structure, where one of the fields in your struct is a pointer to an instance of the struct being defined.  Since the statement isn't complete yet, you can't use the typedef name within the statement.

For example:

```
typedef struct {
    link_t *next;
    void   *data;
} link_t;
```

won't work, because you're trying to use link_t before the compiler has seen the symbol.  Instead, you write it so:

```
typedef struct LL {
    struct LL *next;
    void      *data;
} link_t;
```

and struct LL is known to the compiler one line before you use it.

Comment: You can still use `struct foo` even if `foo` is a type name.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Only if `foo` is both the typedef name *and* the struct name.  If the struct was left anonymous, as my first example, you can't reference it internally.  And per EJP's answer above, naming them both the same has namespace hazards if you transfer the struct to C++.

Comment: The point is that the “functional reason” proposed in this answer for using different names does not explain why a different names would be used. You can use the same name for the tag and the type: `typedef struct foo { struct foo *next; void *data; } foo;` is legal. And EJP’s speculation that the redeclaration of the name is illegal in C++ is incorrect; this is explicitly allowed as per C++ (N3092) 7.1.3 3 and 4. (That is an old draft, but I do not believe it has changed.)

Comment: One could say `typedef struct LL_S LL; struct LL_S { LL *next; };`.  If one wanted to, one could use the name `LL_S` for the tag rather than `LL`, but using different names for the tag will make it easier to enforce a convention of either consistently using the keyword `struct` to create things of a type, or consistently not using it.  Using the same name in both places means that inconsistent usage will be allowed with no diagnostic.

Comment: @ErikJohnson is right, the forward reference is the explanation a Microsoft developer gives: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080327-00/?p=22973

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `struct` tags and `typedef` names are in different namespaces in C. You can only use a `struct` tag after the keyword `struct,` so it is handy to know which is which.

In C++ they are in the same namespace so the issue doesn't arise. Which also means your second example may not be legal C++. Your first example is legal in both languages.

Comment: This is contradictory. Since you can only use a tag after `struct` or `union`, and cannot use a type name after them, there is no confusion. Naming them differently does not provide any disambiguation, so there is nothing handy about it.

Comment: So is the second example legal (in C++) or not?  (I would naively assume it must be, otherwise an unlimited number of legacy C header files would be illegal when pulled into a C++ compilation unit...)

Comment: Redeclaring the class name as a type name is not illegal in C++. Per C++ (N3092, which is an old draft, but I do not believe this has changed) 7.1.3 3, “In a given non-class scope, a typedef specifier can be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that
scope to refer to the type to which it already refers.” Paragraph 4 says “In a given class scope, a typedef specifier can be used to redefine any class-name declared in that scope
that is not also a typedef-name to refer to the type to which it already refers.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's an invalid inference from a false premiss. (1) I didn't use the word 'ambiguous': I said it is 'handy'; and (2) in any case ambiguity resolution is not a prerequisite for something to be handy. It is 'handy' because you know that for any struct X, the struct tag is XTag and the typedef is X.

Comment: @EJP: If the names are the same, you know that for any struct X, the struct tag is X (and appears in the source as `struct X`), and the type name is X (and only appears without `struct`). Naming them differently provides no additional function. Another way of looking at it is that there is no point in adding `Tag` on the end because you already have `struct` on the front.

Comment: @EJP: By the way, resolving “which is which” is disambiguation. Just because you did not use the word does not mean you did not use the concept.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: If 90% of the variables of a struct type declare the variable as `FOO x;` and 10% use `struct FOO x;`, it's probably desirable for those 10% to be changed to omit the keyword `struct`, and that will most likely happen if the compiler won't accept them with the keyword.  Note that outside of the line defining the `typedef`, there's no need for the struct tag to appear anywhere in code.

Comment: @supercat: For what reason is it desirable for the 10% to be changed? What problem could be caused if they are not changed?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It is often easier to spot bugs in code which writes things using a consistent style, than in code where the usage is more varied.  If a code reviewer sees `FOO *x; struct FOO *y; void *p = y;` and later `x=(FOO*)p;` the person may suspect that `x` and `y` will be the same type (making the assignments legal), but would have to inspect the definitions of `FOO` and `struct FOO` to be sure.  By contrast, if the declarations had been `FOO *x; FOO *y;`, there would be no doubt of their being the same type.

Comment: @supercat: If we accept that this is beneficial, then we look to your statement that “that will most likely happen if the compiler won’t accept them with the keyword.” That statement is saying that, if different tag and type names were used, say “FooTag” and “Foo”, then the compiler would reject `struct Foo x;`. But the code is not going to contain such declarations; given the different names, the declarations would be either `struct FooTag x;` or `Foo x;`, and the compiler accepts both and does not reject them. Thus, the code is not guided toward this benefit you claim.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: In general, the documentation for a library will state what identifier names are intended for outside use.  A programmer who is using one library with type `struct FOO` and another with type `BAR` might accidentally type `FOO` or `struct BAR`, but would be unlikely to type `struct BAR_tag` since *he would likely have no reason to know that the name `BAR_tag` even exists*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason within the C standard to use different names for tags and types. They cannot interfere with each other because they are in different name spaces and cannot be used in the same places.

Therefore, the only reason to use different names would be for human psychology. Although other answers have suggested that using different names for tags and types makes it easier to spot them in code, there is never any ambiguity because structure tag names only appear after `struct`, and only structure tag names appear after `struct`. More than that, if they are the same, you cannot accidentally use one where you intend the other. So there is no need to use different names.

The fact that C++ adopted structure tags as class names demonstrates it is unnecessary for there to be any difference.

Answer (score -2):

The point is that SomeStruct will then be a proper type name. So you don't have to type

```
struct SomeStructTag my_struct;
```

In declarations:

```
SomeStruct my_struct;
```

Other than that, IMHO the _t appended to a name stands for type, not tag.

Comment: It should be noted that identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved for POSIX.

Comment: This does not explain why the tag would be different from the type name.

Comment: I didn't get that this was your original question. However, I find that many people think of the struct name as the "explicit/globally unique name", whereas the typedef'd name is considered to be more "colloquial, locally unique".

Though I have never encountered completely different names except for reasons of hiding implementation details (think platform-specific code).