# Segmentation fault on assigning int

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ncurses

I am following the video series ["Coding a Rogue/Nethack clone in c"](https://github.com/wadsworj) and getting a segfault despite the fact that the creator isn't.
This is using ncurses and the menu library.
`gdb` says it's in the function handleInput, when I try to set the x and y.

```c
Pos* handleInput(int input, Player* user) {
    Pos * newPosition;
    newPosition = malloc(sizeof(Pos));
    switch (input)
    {
        /* move up */
        case 'w':
        case 'W':
            newPosition->y = user->pos->y - 1;
            newPosition->x = user->pos->x;
            break;

        /* move down */
        case 's':
        case 'S':
            newPosition->y = user->pos->y + 1;
            newPosition->x = user->pos->x;
            break;

        /* move left */
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            newPosition->y = user->pos->y;
            newPosition->x = user->pos->x - 1;
            break;

        /* move right */
        case 'd':
        case 'D':

            newPosition->y = user->pos->y; // Segfault here
            newPosition->x = user->pos->x + 1;
        default:
            break;
```

Some typedefs:

```
typedef struct Level {
    int level;
    char** tiles;
    int numRooms;
    struct Player* user;
    struct Room** room;
    struct Monster** Mons;
    int numMons;
} Level;
typedef struct Pos {
    int x;
    int y;
} Pos;
typedef struct Player {
Pos* pos;
int atk;
int maxHP;
int xp;
int gold;
int health;
} Player;
typedef struct Monster {
    char string[2];
    char symbol;
    int alive;
    int health;
    int attack;
    int speed;
    int defense;
    int pathfinding;
    Pos* pos;
} Monster;
```

And my game function:

```
int gameLoop()
 {
     int ch;
     Pos* newPosition;
     Level * level;
     level = createLevel(1);
     Player* user = level->user;
     printGameHud(level);
     /* main game loop */
     while ((ch = getch()) != 'q')
     {
         printGameHud(level);
         newPosition = handleInput(ch, user);
         checkPosition(newPosition,  level);
         moveMonster(level);
         move(level->user->pos->y, level->user->pos->x);

         if (level->user->health <= 0)
         {
             return -1;
         }
     }
     return 1;
}
```

Finally, my menu function, which seems to be where this started:

```
void menuLoop () {
     int choice;
     while (true) {
             char* choices[] = {"Start", "Exit"};
         choice = mainMenu(2, choices);
         switch (choice) {
             case START_GAME:
                 gameLoop();
                 clear();
                 break;
             case QUIT_GAME:
                 return;
         }
     }
 }
int closeMenu(int numItems, MENU* menu, ITEM** items){
     unpost_menu(menu);
     free_menu(menu);
     for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
         free_item(items[i]);
     }
     return 1;
 }
int mainMenu(int numItems, char* items[]) {
     int c, i, value;
     MENU* menu;
     ITEM* current;
     ITEM** menuItems = malloc(sizeof(**menuItems) * numItems);
     for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
         menuItems[i] = new_item(items[i], "");
     }
     menuItems[i] = (ITEM*)NULL;
     menu = new_menu((ITEM**)menuItems);
     post_menu(menu);
     refresh();
     while (true) {
         c = getch();
         switch(c){
             case KEY_DOWN:
                 menu_driver(menu, REQ_DOWN_ITEM);
                 break;
             case KEY_UP:
                 menu_driver(menu, REQ_UP_ITEM);
                 break;
             case 10: 
                 current = current_item(menu);
                 value = item_index(current);
                 closeMenu(numItems, menu, menuItems);
                 return value;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: If it is crashing at `user->pos->y` then `user` or `pos` may be `NULL`. Looks like `user` gets created in `createLevel()` so maybe add that function to the question.

Comment: Health of player seems to be fillled with garbage. 124422462(4) is printed when it should be 20 (20)

Comment: In `mainMenu()` at `menuItems[i] = (ITEM*)NULL;` you write past the end of the array.

Comment: Isolate where the problem is using a debugger, then if by then you don't know how to fix it, post just enough code to reproduce that specific problem along with a clear explanation of what you are seeing for a specific input, and what you expected to see.  ( [mcve] ).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You should post that as the answer, since that line will likely yield a seg fault indeed.

Comment: I see that could be the problem, but the original did it, so I don't see how to fix it.

Comment: I just glanced through the tutorial and it seems to have other issues. Ex, `Room ** rooms; rooms = malloc(sizeof(Room)*6);` Maybe you need to find a new tutorial.

Comment: @Lundin It is definitely _an_ error, but we don't think we can know if it is _the_ error without a [mcve].

Comment: @ARIFISHER I see two problems in the allocation of `menuItems`. The element size is wrong (should be `sizeof(*menuItems)`, not `sizeof(**menuItems)`) and the number of items is wrong (should be `(numItems + 1)` to allow for storing a NULL pointer at the end). It should be `ITEM** menuItems = malloc(sizeof(*menuItems) * (numItems + 1));`

Comment: In all of your struct definitions, eg `typedef struct Monster {...} Monster;`, you are using the same symbol for struct tag _and_ for struct alias (typedef) which causes one to mask the other, and can be problematic.  Suggest that you use unique symbols for each of these struct parts, eg: `typedef struct Monster {...} Monster_t;`

Comment: @ryyker I don't get you. Surely the `menuItems[i] = (ITEM*)NULL;` line is equivalent to `menuItems[numItems] = (ITEM*)NULL;` so the `+ 1` is needed?

Comment: @ryyker structure tag names are not in the same namespace as typedef ids, so the one does not mask the other. You may be thinking of C++?

Comment: @IanAbbott - I just noticed that the symbol `ITEM` definition seems to be missing, so I do not know what the shape of the object is that is being allocated memory, so for now, my comment about allocation is defunct  I will delete it.   Regarding the struct comment, its not illegal, but it is [problematic for reasons listed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20552739/645128).

Comment: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/menus.html It uses menu

Comment: @ryyker Opinions may differ on whether using the same id for a struct tag and a typedef alias of that struct type is problematic or not, so let's agree to disagree on that point. (It may have been problematic in ye olden days before ANSI C, but any code using parameter type lists in function specifiers shouldn't care about that. Some ancient versions of C didn't even have distinct namespaces for struct members.)

Comment: @ARIFISHER In the link you posted, notice the `n_choices + 1` in the `calloc` call.