# Structure inside structure in C

Tags: c, struct

I am learning C and relatively new to it.

I am having trouble with Structs and I am trying to get a structure variable to hold the values `firstName`, `lastName`, `tries`, `won`, and `percentage`. The last three themselves have to be contained in another struct inside the first struct. My code is below, also if anyone could explain the difference between structure tags and variable types that would help a lot. I understand there may be a lot of errors in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct team{
    char firstName[40];                     
    char lastName[40];

    struct stats{
        int tries;

        int won;

        float percentage;
    } record;
}; 

int main(){
  //Assign variable name and test print to check that struct is working.
  struct team player;
  strcpy(player.firstName,"Michael");
  strcpy(player.lastName,"Jordan");

  struct stats player;
  player.tries = 16;
  player.won = 14;
  player.percentage = ((player.won/player.tries)*100);

  printf("First Name: \t %s \n", player.firstName);
  printf("Last Name: \t %s \n", player.lastName);
  printf("Tries: \t %d \n", player.tries);
  printf("Won: \t %d \n", player.won);
  printf("Percentage: \t %f \n", player.percentage);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. You say you are learning C, and your code looks like C. Removing the C++ tag.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought they were the same!

Comment: By the way, are you sure your real code have two different variables named `player`? You might want to read about [SSCCEs](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When accessing struct inside struct, do it like this:

```
player.record.tries = 16;
player.record.won = 14;
player.record.percentage = (((float)player.record.won/player.record.tries)*100);
```

As for the struct tag, with the `struct team` type, `team` is the struct tag, while `struct team` together makes a type. You may use `typedef` to use struct type without `struct` keyword.

```
typedef struct team team;
```

Comment: Don't forget to cast the numerator or denominator to float in that division, or you will find that their record is always zero.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Done. Didn't notice that part, nice spot.

Comment: What do you mean by cast it to float? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @mungostrap In integer arithmetic, result of `3/4` is `0`, but `(float)3/4` is the float number `0.75`.

Comment: Ah perfect, that makes a sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You know how to access structure members (e.g. `player.firstname`), accessing nested structure members are just the same, with the "dot" member selection operator:

```
player.record.tries = ...;
```

Comment: Is Record the name or variable type? I want it to be the type. When I put the above in my code, and change every reference to player.record.tries etc I get an error saying that the struct team has no member 'won' or 'tries'.

Comment: @mungostrap It's a structure member variable inside the `team` structure, just like e.g. `firstname`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler shall issue an error because you defined the same name player having different types

```
struct team player;                             //Assign variable name and test print to check that 
// ...
struct stats player;
```

You should write

```
struct team player;                             //Assign variable name and test print to check that struct is working.
strcpy(player.firstName,"Michael");
strcpy(player.lastName,"Jordan");

player.record.tries = 16;
player.record.won = 14;
player.record.percentage = ((player.record.won / player.record.tries)*100);
```

Or you could write

```
int main(){
  //Assign variable name and test print to check that struct is working.
  struct team player;
  strcpy(player.firstName,"Michael");
  strcpy(player.lastName,"Jordan");

  struct stats s;
  s.tries = 16;
  s.won = 14;
  s.percentage = ((s.won/s.tries)*100);

  player.record = s;
  // ,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also save typing of `struct` everywhere by `typedef`ing it.  See this [question and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions) for more.