# What does the following struct definition mean?

Tags: c++, struct

In a few places in the code I have a `struct` definition that looks like this:

```
typedef struct tagNameOfStruct{
  //some methods and members
}T_NameOfStruct, * PT_NameOfStruct, FAR LPT_NameOfStruct;

typedef struct tagNameOfStructLists{
  //some methods and members
}T_NameOfStructLists, * PT_NameOfStructLists, FAR LPT_NameOfStructLists;
 typedef pair<T_NameOfStruct, T_NameOfStructLists> CStructPair;
 typedef map<T_NameOfStruct, T_NameOfStructLists> CStructMap;
```

Than I see that inside a method within a loop the following line of code

```
T_NameOfStruct instance;
T_NameOfStructLists listInstance;
m_MapInstance.insert(CStructPair(instance, listInstance));
//structMapInstance is a members of method class of type CStructMap
```

That instance is being inserted to data-structure which is used outside the scope of the function.It is passed to the data-structure by reference.

1. Shouldn't instance die when we leave the function scope?
2. What does the last line of the struct definition mean?

Edit **---- Why this is not a duplicate, please reopen----** :
The * PT_NameOfStruct, FAR LPT_NameOfStruct in the struct definition are different from the question you guys linked too. Also there is the issue of the passing the instance by ref while it is defines on the method stack. The strange thing is that the code works so I'm wondering what I'm missing here. Why don't I get an exception while trying to access destroyed objects in a different function which iterates over the data structure. 
Still think it's a duplicate?

Comment: please provide "insertion" code so that we may see a full picture

Comment: It is a stock question, and has been answered a lot of times. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions?rq=1

Comment: have a look at this blog (http://arraynotfound.blogspot.in/), i have written article about "tag name as struct", you can have a idea

Comment: @Vinoth Your blog is irrelevant. This is C++, where tag names and typedefs are not in different namespaces.

Comment: Wait you guys I know what typedef struct tagNameOfStruct{
  //some methods and members
}T_NameOfStruct; means. There are loads of stuff here which is going on which I don't know. Don't close this yet\

Comment: @qballer So what is it that you *don't* know exactly? If your question hasn't been answered, maybe you need to clarify it?

Comment: @EJP All I meant is not to close it as a duplicate. You and mike gave really good answers. I just need to understand something from Mike and I think his answer will be valid.

Comment: As to the `T_NameOfStruct, * PT_NameOfStruct, FAR* LPT_NameOfStruct` part. The syntax of a declaration consists of two parts, a sequence of specifiers, and a comma-separated list of declarators. At least one specifier must specify a type; specifiers may be compound and define new types.

Comment: Your declaration has two specifiers, `typedef` and `struct…{…}`, and three declarators, `T_NameOfStruct`, `* PT_NameOfStruct`, `FAR* LPT_NameOfStruct`. Declarators introduce names and assign them types. Were there no `typedef`, `T_NameOfStruct`, `PT_NameOfStruct`, and `LPT_NameOfStruct` would be names of objects, and their types would be such that the type of expressions `T_NameOfStruct`, `* PT_NameOfStruct`, `* LPT_NameOfStruct` would be `struct…{…}`. However, with `typedef`, the declaration introduces type names instead of objects.

Comment: `FAR` is a remnant of old days when 16-bit Intel processors used segmented memory address space and there was distinction between full 'far' pointers (containing both segment and offset; denoted by a `LP` prefix in Hungarian notation) and 'near' pointers (containing only offset, so that to use them a segment had to be assumed; denoted by a `NP` prefix in Hungarian notation). After a `FAR` or `NEAR` a `*` or `&` *must* follow, therefore I assumed that there must have been a typo in your original post. Nowadays, `FAR` and `NEAR` are empty macros kept for compatibility.

Comment: And at last, as to instances passed by reference. The constructor of `std::pair` (assuming that it is `std::`) accepts const references, but what it actually does is making copies. `std::map::insert` also accepts a reference, but stores copies.

Comment: How does a ref store copy? They get a ref to the object and make a full copy of it? What if it contains other references.

Comment: @qballer, by the means of copy-initialization or move-initialization which means calling a copy-constructor or move-constructor of the structures in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't instance die when we leave the function scope?

Yes. If the code you haven't shown us actually uses a reference to it after that, then it's wrong. But since we can't see it, we can only guess whether or not it does that.

**UPDATE**: Now you've shown us what's actually happening, it's being passed to `map::insert`, which stores a copy of its argument (even though it takes the argument by reference). There's no problem when `instance` itself is destroyed, assuming it has valid copy semantics.

> What does the ending of the struct definition mean?

It declares:

- a class called `tagNameOfStruct`.
- an alias for the class type, called `T_NameOfStruct`. In C++ this is completely pointless; in C, some people have a bad habit of doing that to avoid typing `struct` when specifying the type.
- an alias for a pointer to the type, called `PT_NameOfStruct`. This is an even worse idea than the first typedef, since it hides the important information that something is a pointer.
- an alias for an obsolete "far" pointer to the type, called `LPT_NameOfStruct`. That's a hangover from 16-bit platforms; on a modern platform it will be the same as the regular pointer type.

Don't use this as a model for how to declare class types. It's better to keep it simple:

```
class NameOfStruct {  // or "struct", if you want members to be public by default
    // members
};

NameOfStruct instance;  // No need for a typedef
NameOfStruct * pointer; // Make it clear that it's a pointer
```

Comment: The pair constructor takes const _T1& _V1, const _T2& _V2 and the map insert takes a const value_type& _X. This might be stupid question but how is this not by ref?

Comment: @qballer: Sorry, you're right, they are passed by reference. But both the `pair` constructor, and `insert` itself, take copies of the arguments. I'll update the question to be pedantically accurate.

Answer (score 1):

> struct tagNameOfStruct{

In C++, struct tags have equivalent status to typedefs. Not so in C.

> T_NameOfStruct

This is another and better name for `tagNameOfStruct`.

> *PT_NameOfStruct

This is a typedef for a *pointer* to `NameOfStruct`.

> FAR LPT_NameOfStruct;

This is an obsolete name for a FAR pointer to `NameOfStruct`, given that `near` and `far` pointers have meant the same thing since Windows 95 as far as I can see. Note that this is because of the preceding `*` in the preceding typename, which carries over to this one because of C's strange pointer syntax.

The only things you need to worry about here are `NameOfStruct`, which is a typedef for the struct itself, and `PT_NameOfStruct`, which is a pointer to it. The rest is fluff.

> That instance is being inserted to data-structure which is used outside the scope of the function. It is passed to the data-structure by reference.
>
> Shouldn't instance die when we leave the function scope?

Yes. You have found a bug.

> What does the ending of the struct definition mean?

'The ending of the struct definition' means that this is the end of the struct definition. What else would it mean? Did you mean the ending of the *declaration?* Did you mean everything I've stated above?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers,

```
struct s
{

}
```

In above struct definition you can use as follows

in c for declaring instance you should do like this

```
struct s instance1;
```

in c++ you should define as follows

```
struct s instance1; (or)
s instance1;
```

Both are valid in c++.

In c instead of using struct s at all area you can use typedef for simplification.