# Wrong syntax for typedef with struct?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have the following code below.

```
typedef struct person Person;
    Person {
        char* name;
        int age;
    };
```

From what I understand, typedef will substitute "struct person" with Person. So when making the struct, it is equal to writing :

```
    struct person {
        char* name;
        int age;
    };
```

Is this thinking correct? 
Because I am getting an error an error of the first line of the struct.

**error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token**
This error is referring to the line : *Person {*

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: A typedef is not the same as a macro; it doesn't substitute like that.

Comment: Ok, if I have the "typedef struct person Person" , how can I make a struct of Person?

Comment: `typedef struct person { char *name; int age; } Person;`

Comment: This answer has some good background on this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this

```
typedef struct person Person;
struct person  {
        char* name;
        int age;
};
```

Then you can use `Person` for all *usages* of the `struct`.

also there is no need in different capitalization

```
typedef struct person person;
```

would do equally well.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do what you want is:

```
struct person {
    char* name;
    int age;
};
typedef struct person Person;
```

Or, if you want to accomplish this in one instruction, you could do:

```
typedef struct person {
    char* name;
    int age;
} Person;
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
        char* name;
        int age;
    } Person;
```