# What does the struct declaration typedef struct A { … } B; mean?

Tags: c, struct

What is the name of the struct below — `node_t` or `node`?
Why is there any difference?

```
typedef struct node_t
{
    int data;
    struct node_t *right, *left;
}   node;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [typedef struct vs struct definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

Comment: It means putting an alias `node` to `struct node_t`. (`node_t` is struct tag name in C)

Answer (score 4):

You are defining a name (`node`) for the `struct node_t`.

It allows you to create the structure using `node myStruct` instead of  `struct node_t myStruct`.

Comment: So just for complete understanding - node is related to the typedef? and allows me to call the struct without using the word struct? and the name of the struct is node_t?

Comment: it's the same as making a new type for an int -
typedef int myint; but for a struct.

Comment: Yes, yes, and no.  The name of the struct (struct node_t) is node;

Comment: @noyuzi `typedef foo bar` declares the type `bar` as a synonym to `foo`, so `foo my_var` is equivalent to `bar my_var`. In this case, `foo`=`struct node_t` and `bar`=`node`.

Comment: Note that C++ has different rules and would not require the `typedef`; you could write `struct node { int data; node *right; node *left; };` and then use `node` as the name of a type (indeed, you've already used `node` as the name of the type inside the structure).