# What is the diffrence between struct and typedef?

Tags: c, typedef

What is the diffrence between this :

```
struct foo
{
   ......
};
```

and

```
typedef struct foo
{
   ......
};
```

Comment: In this case, beyond the duplicate [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions), another difference is the second snippet wouldn't compile, as there is no alias name.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c -- `struct` declarations behave differently in C++ than in C.

Comment: A `struct` declaration defines a new structure type. A `typedef` declaration merely creates a new name for an existing type. The syntax permits you to combine them into a single declaration.

Comment: I've expanded on this in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26389105/827263) that I just posted to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1675351/827263).

Answer (score 0):

First declares a structure tag `foo` while second define a structure type `foo`.

Comment: i.e. in the former your code would declare variable bar as struct foo bar; in the latter it would be foo bar.

Comment: Dowvoter care to explain ?