# typedef struct nested pointer undefined error

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, typedef

Im making a linked list using a typedef'ed struct, but the compiler is telling my that my new type is undefined.

```
typedef struct valholder
{
    char* id;
    union
    {
        int ival;
        float fval;
        char* cval;
    };
    valholder* next;
};
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a number of other very similar questions.  The difficulty, as ever, is finding the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `typedef` is:

```
typedef <type> <alias>
```

Where `<type>` is an existing type name or a type expression (like `struct {...}`) and `<alias>` is the new type name.

Here's one way of defining your data strucure without referring to the alias:

```
typedef struct valholder_s {
  char* id;
  union {
     int ival;
     float fval;
     char* cval;
  };
  struct valholder_s* next;
} valholder;
```

Comment: The `_s` seems like an unnecessary change.

Comment: Why is it that valholder needs to be re-defined as a struct when it's already been typedef'd?

Comment: This is a habit I picked up from reading other people's code a long time ago. I guess that if the namespaces for structs and typenames are different maybe it isn't needed.

Comment: Actually I often happen a `_t` at the end of the alias to indicate that it's a typename, but here I chose to stick to OP's choice.

Comment: @ChrisPhillips the typedef happens after the struct definition, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions for a far better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   typedef struct valholder
    {
        char* id;
        union
        {
            int ival;
            float fval;
            char* cval;
        };
        struct valholder* next;
    } valholder;
```