# What does it mean: "typedef struct{...} VNode,AdjList[20]"

Tags: c, struct

I am a C starter and learning some data structures of Graph.
I read a segement of C code on wikipedia today:

```
    #define MAX_VERTEX_NUM 20
    typedef struct ArcNode
    {
       int adjvex; /* Position of Arc's Vertex */
       struct ArcNode *nextarc; /* Pointer to next Arc */
       InfoType *info; /* Weight） */
     }ArcNode; /* Node */
     typedef struct
     {
       VertexType data; /* Vertex Information */
       ArcNode *firstarc; /* Location to the first list node */
     }VNode,AdjList[MAX_VERTEX_NUM]; /* Head Node */
     typedef struct
     {
       AdjList vertices;
       int vexnum,arcnum; /* Vertex count and Arc count */
       GraphKind kind; /* type of Garph, directed, undirected..*/
     }ALGraph;`
```

I read several related post here such as "[typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)", but I am still a bit confused on this usage:

```
typedef struct  {....  }VNode,AdjList[MAX_VERTEX_NUM];
```

So what is AdjList? It is an array? If so, what does this statement mean:

```
AdjList vertices;
```

Thanks.
Reference:http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%82%BB%E6%8E%A5%E8%A1%A8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AdjList` is an array of size `MAX_VERTEX_NUM` of the type defined in the `struct`.

Declaration in C are a little funny.

```
typedef struct {...} AdjList[MAX_VERTEX_NUM]
```

Should be read as `AdjList` is defined as an array of size `MAX_VERTEX_NUM` of the type defined in the struct. This is a type, which means you can declare variables to be instances of this type.

Comment: If `AdjList` is an array, why there is a definition like: `AdjList vertices;`? `AdjList`looks like a kind of type here...Thanks a lot for your quick reply.

Comment: AdjList is another name for the struct. Just like you can define an array of ints as int[40] you can define an array of the struct as AdjList[40].

Answer (score 2):

`AdjList` is a type "array of the type defined in the `struct`" of size `MAX_VERTEX_NUM`.

A simpler example demonstrating what is going on :

```
typedef int myintarray[10];

int main()
{
   myintarray array; // same as "int array[10]"

   array[2] = 2 ;
}
```