# C binary search tree deletion implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement the deletion function for a binary search tree in C, however I am running into problems.

I have the following structs for the tree and the nodes

```
typedef struct {
    double value;

    struct Node *parent;
    struct Node *right_child;
    struct Node *left_child;
} Node;

typedef struct {
    struct Node *root;
} Tree;
```

I also have an  in-order traversal function

```
void inOrderTraversalNode(Node *n) {

    if (n != NULL) {

        inOrderTraversalNode(n->left_child);
        printf("%f\n", n->value);
        inOrderTraversalNode(n->right_child);
    }
}
```

A subtree minimum function

```
Node * minimum(Node *n) {

    while (n->left_child != NULL) {
        n = n->left_child;
    }

    return n;
}
```

and a transplant function

```
void transplant(Tree *t, Node *u, Node *v) {

    Node *p = u->parent;

    //replace u's parent's child pointer to v
    if (p == NULL) {
        t->root = v;
    } else if (u == p->left_child) {
        p->left_child = v;
    } else {
        p->right_child = v;
    }

    //set v's parent pointer to u's parent
    if (v != NULL) {
        v->parent = p;
    }
}
```

And finally I have the delete function

```
void delete(Tree *t, Node *z) {

    //if node z has no left subtree, replace z with right subtree and vice-versa.
    if (z->left_child == NULL) {
        transplant(t, z, z->right_child);

    } else if (z->right_child == NULL) {
        transplant(t, z, z->left_child);
    } else {
        Node *y = minimum(z->right_child);

        if (y->parent != z) {
            transplant(t, y, y->right_child);

            Node *y_right_child = y->right_child;

            y_right_child = z->right_child;
            y_right_child->parent = y;
        }
        transplant(t, z, y);

        Node *y_left_child = y->left_child;

        y_left_child = z->left_child;
        y_left_child->parent = y;
    }

}
```

However when I run the following code in main

```
int main(void) {

        Node n1;
        Node n2;
        Node n3;
        Node n4;
        Node n5;
        Node n6;
        Node n7;
        Node n8;

        n1.value = 4;
        n1.parent = NULL;
        n1.left_child = &n2;
        n1.right_child = &n5;

        n2.value = 2;
        n2.parent = &n1;
        n2.left_child = &n3;
        n2.right_child = &n4;

        n3.value = 1;
        n3.parent = &n2;
        n3.left_child = NULL;
        n3.right_child = NULL;

        n4.value = 3;
        n4.parent = &n2;
        n4.left_child = NULL;
        n4.right_child = NULL;

        n5.value = 6;
        n5.parent = &n1;
        n5.left_child = &n6;
        n5.right_child = &n7;

        n6.value = 5;
        n6.parent = &n5;
        n6.left_child = NULL;
        n6.right_child = NULL;

        n7.value = 7;
        n7.parent = &n5;
        n7.left_child = NULL;
        n7.right_child = NULL;


        Tree t;

        t.root = &n1;

        printf("In order traversal\n");
        inOrderTraversalNode(t.root);

        printf("Delete node\n");
        delete(&t,&n1);
        inOrderTraversalNode(t.root);


        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

It returns `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` for the first traversal. But it returns `1,2,3,4,7` for the second traversal after deleting `n5` which is incorrect because it misses the `n6` node containing `5`.  I do not understand why this is happening.  I have inserted some print statements in the delete function and the `n7` node is adding the `n6` node as its left child, but for some reason it doesn't get printed during the traversal.

Comment: Can you post the rest of `main`, so that there is a complete program that can be compiled and run?  It will be easier to find the bug by running with a debugger than by staring at the code.

Comment: Suspicious code in `delete`: `Node *y_right_child = y->right_child;  y_right_child = z->right_child;`  You initialize the variable and then immediately assign it another value?

Comment: For what it's worth, when I run it, after running `delete` the tree consists *only* of a single node with value `5`.

Comment: I was trying to do ```y->right_child->parent=y``` but this gives the error ```error: incomplete definition of type 'struct Node'```

Comment: The first line should say `typedef struct Node {`.  There must be a question here on SO explaining why that is...  You should have got a ton of warnings without it.

Comment: Aha! that fixed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code caught my attention:

```
        Node *y_right_child = y->right_child;

        y_right_child = z->right_child;
        y_right_child->parent = y;
```

You assign a value to variable `y_right_child`, and then you immediately replace it with a different value.  What you intend to do, it appears, is transfer node `z`'s right child to node `y`.  That would be this:

```
        y->right_child = z->right_child;
        y->right_child->parent = y;
```

You don't need to remember or modify `y`'s original right child at that point, because that was already handled via function `transplant()`.

There is a similar issue with the other child-transfer code:

```
    Node *y_left_child = y->left_child;

    y_left_child = z->left_child;
    y_left_child->parent = y;
```

Again, you assign a value to the variable, and then immediately replace it.  What you appear really to want is this:

```
    y->left_child = z->left_child;
    y->left_child->parent = y;
```

Note that because node `y` started out as the minimum value from its subtree, you can be certain that `y->left_child` is initially NULL.

Comment: I see.  I actually had this at first but the problem is that ```y->right_child->parent``` gives me the error ```error: incomplete definition of type 'struct Node'```

Answer (score 1):

As your code stands, the type `struct Node` is not declared or defined anywhere.  The `typedef` at the top of your code doesn't accomplish this; it defines a different type called `Node`.  See [typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions?rq=1).  This should have caused a ton of warnings in your compilation.  Don't ignore them!

It also seems to have been the indirect cause of the real bug.  In `delete` you have the code

```
        Node *y_right_child = y->right_child;

        y_right_child = z->right_child;
        y_right_child->parent = y;
```

which is clearly not the right thing.  You want to change the right child pointer of `y`.  But when you wrote what you really want:

```
        y->right_child = z->right_child;
        y->right_child->parent = y;
```

you got an error because `y->right_child` is of the undefined type `struct Node *` and therefore can't be dereferenced.  Rather than fix this properly, you introduced the local variable `y_right_child`, which at least made the code compile.  But what good is code that compiles, if it doesn't work? Assigning to `y_right_child` just changes the value of the local variable; it doesn't change the value of the pointer `y->right_child` itself.

Changing the very first line to `typedef struct Node {` causes `struct Node` to be defined as what you want (and the typedef `Node` is defined as the same type).  Then changing `y_right_child` to `y->right_child` and removing the variable `y_right_child` altogether, and doing the same for `y->left_child`, the delete works as intended.