# C language and Queues/linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

Can someone please explain the code below. I am new to C and trying to figure it out. why do we have queueNodeT at the end?

```
typedef char queueElementT;

typedef struct queueNodeTag {
  queueElementT element;
  struct queueNodeTag *next;
} queueNodeT;
```

Comment: That's for the `typedef`. It combines a `struct` declaration and a typedef name for the struct.

Comment: A `typedef` declaration declares an alias for a type.  In this case `queueElementT` is declared to be an alias for `char`.  Also, `queueNodeT` is declared to be an alias for `struct queueNodeTag`, and `struct queueNodeTag` is furthermore defined as a `struct` having the specified members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

queueNodeT is the name of the type that the typedef statement is trying to create.

An alternate way to specify this is:

```
struct queueNodeTag {
    ...
};
typedef struct queueNodeTag queueNodeT;
```

In C (vs. C++), "struct queueNodeTag" just defines a struct named "queueNodeTag".  In C++ [should you get there], this would also define a type named "queueNodeTag"

When creating a pointer variable to the struct, it's slightly shorter to use:

```
queueNodeT *my_pointer;
```

than:

```
struct queueNodeTag *my_pointer;
```

The trailing "T" is just a coding convention to denote that it's a type name and not a variable.  You can use others.  Mine is:

```
struct mystructname {
    ...
};
typedef struct mystructname mystructname_t;
typedef mystructname_t *mystructname_p;
```

Using mystructname_p, you can change:

```
struct mystructname *my_pointer;
mystructname_t *my_pointer;
```

into:

```
mystructname_p my_pointer;
```

The "_t" is fairly common.  The "_p" thing is my convention, but, I believe other conventions define pointers to types as "p<Mytype>", such as "pMystructName".  I much prefer using a suffix for this [and "snake case" notation rather than the "camel hump" notation in your example].

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down part by part.

This line simply tells you that `queueElementT` is defined as `char` here. Meaning you can write either `queueElementT` or `char`, both will work.

```
typedef char queueElementT;
```

Now here is the actual `struct`. It contain two variables, the element it is holding, in this case a `char`. It then also tells which element is next in the `queue`.

```
typedef struct queueNodeTag {
    queueElementT element;
    struct queueNodeTag *next;
} queueNodeT;
```

More of that can be read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions) answer.

A demonstration:

```
int count (queueNodeTag q) {
    int i = 0;

    if (q == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (q.next == null) {
        return 1;
    }

    while (q.next != null) {
        q = q.next;
        i++;
    }

    return i;   
}
```

Three cases to handle.

1. `q` is `null`, the `queue` is empty. Return 0.
2. `q.next` is `null`, the `queue` only contains one element. Return 1.
3. Repeat until `q.next` is separated from `null`, increment `i` as we go. A better name for i might be `elements` or something similar.

*This code is untested as I currently do not have a C compiler at hand. Someone who has one available can perhaps verify that no mistake has been done?*