# What's the difference between these two declarations?

Tags: c++

I am only asking in context of C++.

```
struct x1 { ... };
typedef struct { ... } x2;
int main()
{
    x1 a;
    x2 b;
}
```

Comment: In C++, there is no difference (but in C)

Answer (score 4):

The first defines a class with the name `x1`.

The second defines an unnamed class and also defines a type alias, by the name `x2` to it.

The difference is very subtle in C++. You can observe the difference by trying to declare a function by the same name:

```
void x1(); // OK
void x2(); // not OK, redefined as a different type of symbol
```

In practice, you should avoid defining a function by the same name as a class within the same namespace, so this difference hardly ever comes up. The first one is typically preferred because it's simpler.

In C, the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions) affects the use of the identifier a bit more.