# Singly Linked List c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand Singly Linked List by reading some codes and making sense out of it. 
This code, found on this site
 http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-single-linked-list/, 
has

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;

} *start;
```

I understand what int info and struct node *next does, but what does the extra *start mean after closing the brackets?

Thanks!

Comment: This is C. In C++ the second struct is not required.

Comment: @LokiAstari ok thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`start` is a variable of type `struct node*` - my guess is it is the head of the list.

If you find it easier to split the type and the variable:

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;

};

struct node* start;
```

Since this is C++ you can also simplify to `node* start;`

Comment: ah ok thanks. I'm assuming we can put that somewhere else correct? Where else can we insert that instead of there? It seems a bit out of place to me and makes it a bit confusing...

Comment: Since this is tagged C++ the typedef is not required. Nor is the second struct.

Answer (score 1):

```
    struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;

};
```

Think of the above as just a template for something you will be using in future.

So when you want to structure your data using the above struct you will need to define a variable or instantiate the struct in memory as shown below

Something like

```
struct node mynode;
or 
struct node* mynodeptr = new node;
```

To answer your subsequent question the above can be done wheresoever you need a `node` variable instantiated. So yes it doesn't have to be always done the way it was done in your original question.

As for `typedef`ing a `struct` there's a good discussion on why you would use it. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

Comment: oh I see thanks! Im having a bit of a hard time determining where to put what? Would it be appropriate to set that up in the public section of single_llist?

Comment: @rose I'm not entirely sure what you mean by public section of the `single_llist`. Structures are usually declared completely in header files if you plan on using them across several source files of a project. However you could both declare and instantiate within a single source file too, keeping the struct localized to just that one source file. This depends on the requirements of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It is a variable of type struct node.
It is used as the head of the linked list.Many times reference to traverse in the linked list.
Hope this helps.