# c - Error: "incomplete type is not allowed" , IAR compiler

Tags: c, data-structures, incomplete-type

Please advise, what's wrong?

in **.h**

```
struct {
      uint8_t time;
      uint8_t type;
      uint8_t phase;
      uint8_t status;
} Raw_data_struct;  


typedef struct Raw_data_struct Getst_struct;

void Getst_resp(Getst_struct Data);
```

in **.c**

```
void Getst_resp(Getst_struct  Data) //Here Error: incomplete type is not allowed                                        
{

};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is due to the mixture when declaring the 'struct Raw_data_struct'. You can have a look of the post [typedef struct vs struct definitions [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions).

To declare your struct, you have to use:

```
struct Raw_data_struct {
  uint8_t time;
  uint8_t type;
  uint8_t phase;
  uint8_t status;
};
```

Instead of :

```
struct {
  uint8_t time;
  uint8_t type;
  uint8_t phase;
  uint8_t status;
} Raw_data_struct;
```

If you want to declare both the struct and the typedef, you have to use:

```
typedef struct Raw_data_struct {
  uint8_t time;
  uint8_t type;
  uint8_t phase;
  uint8_t status;
} Getst_struct;
```