# error: unknown type name struct

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve Conway's Game of Life in C. I have written a .h file containing all my functions, yet I receive the following error within the header file:
error: unknown type name "matrix"

This is the beginning of the header file, which contains my struct declaration and the 1st function:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 1000
struct matrix{
    int Val, Next;
};
void intro_date(int nr_elem, matrix a[MAX][MAX]){
    int x,y;
    printf("Enter the line and the column of the element which you wish to read within the matrix: \n");
    while(nr_elem){
        scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
        a[x][y].Val=1;
        --nr_elem;
    }
}
```

Comment: In C you can not ommit the `struct` keyword, `matrix a[MAX][MAX]` should be `struct  matrix a[MAX][MAX]` (or use a `typedef`)

Comment: Here is explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions

Comment: Or the definition should be `typedef struct matrix{
    int Val, Next;
} matrix;`.

Comment: You should not put function implementations in C header files, only their prototypes.  Including the implementation as well tends to produce duplicate definitions, which are not allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You defined a structure called `struct matrix`.  This is not the same as `matrix`, as struct definitions must be preceeded by the `struct` keyword.

Change your function definition to:

```
void intro_date(int nr_elem, struct matrix a[MAX][MAX])
```

Also, you should not put code into a header file.  Only type definitions and declarations belong there.  If more than one source file were to include this header, the object file created for each will contain a copy of the function `intro_date()`.  Upon attempting to link those files, you'll get an error stating `intro_date()` was redefined.

The definition of `intro_date` should exist in exactly one source file.  Then the header would contain just the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Typedef on struct declaration its "new name".

```
typedef struct matrix{
    int Val, Next;
} matrix;
```

Or specify on new instance creation explictly that it is struct:

```
struct matrix a[MAX][MAX];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
    void intro_date(int nr_elem, matrix a[MAX][MAX]){
```

use

```
    void intro_date(int nr_elem, struct matrix a[MAX][MAX]){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Struct Keyword before that.

For C compilers, you have to user struct keyword whereas In C++, the struct keyword is optional.
For Ease in C, you can typedef it.

```
typedef struct _matrix{
    int Val, Next;
}matrix;
```