# How to properly copy a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct element and I want to copy the element data (in all fields) to another element.

So if this is the struct

```
struct Node{
  char* name;
  char type;
  char* path;
};
```

and this is my copy function :

```
struct Node Node_cp(struct Node member)
{
  struct Node NewMember;
  NewMember=malloc(sizeof(struct Node))
  //**Here i get error : Assigning to struct Node from incompatible type void* (why ?)**

  NewMember.name=member.name;
  NewMember.type=member.type;
  NewMember.path=member.path;

  return NewMember;
}
```

**- My Questions :**

1. why do i get this error on the malloc ?
2. is this the right way to do it ? I'm going
3. should i use malloc on **newMember.path=malloc(sizeof(member.path))**
   and in all other fields as well ?

   editing to explain why my question is different from using typedef in struct because the system think this is a duplicate question : Well as i understand in C this are totally different questions. I asked about copying an element and not on typedef :<

Thanks

Comment: `struct Node NewMember;` => `struct Node *NewMember;` make that a pointer. then change all dots to `->` ... and buy a C book

Comment: We have a [list of good C books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303)....

Comment: can we close this now? thanks

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks. can you recommend on a C book ? especially one that focus pointers and know how to explain scopes, etc.. ? nvm just saw the answer of DevSoalr Thanks

Comment: Of course @Jean after the accepted answer, we're in it for the hats aren't we?

Comment: no, last book I read on C was a lame Turbo C book round 1991 :) but there are probably a lot of online tutorials around, and the list quoted above has some very good entries.

Comment: @erans feel free to stop in [C chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c) to ask questions for clarifications on your readings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

Comment: @MaximMakhun This is not the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc` returns a pointer to space in memory.  You are trying to assign it to a non-pointer type.  `NewMember` already has space allocated to it (in the scope of this function). To "fix" it, change the type of `NewMember`.

`struct Node * NewMember = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`

Side note: you're going to want this function to return a pointer, or you should pass it two pointers to `struct Node`, where one parameter is `src` and one is `dest`, similar to the concept of `memcpy`.  I mention this because once `NewMember` leaves scope, accessing the returned value is undefined behavior.

You will encounter issues with the latter part of the function as well--be sure to revise it and search how to properly copy things like strings in C.

Comment: that's not the only issue...

Comment: I didn't even read the second half of the function -_-

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i return a pointer instead i can access all his fields normally when i'm out of the function scope ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to remember to `free` pointers when you're done with them.

Comment: Great thanks. now i'm more confident in what im doing :) this basically answered my question here. the explanation that malloc returns a pointer was a great help.

Comment: Just in case you're learning C now with an eye on learning C++ later... [Don't do that, learn C++ straight away.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk&t=428s)

Comment: No.. I'm learning C as part of my degree. I just need to get used to it after java :(

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the newMember instance of your struct as a pointer, because the returning type of malloc() is of type void* .....then you should assign a pointer to a pointer.

By the way you'll need to access the structure members by -> operator instead of the dot (e.g `NewMember->name = member.name;`)

Also, i think you should consider passing a constant pointer to the function, it's better if we are talking limiting memory consumption.

so the function prototype could become as :

```
struct Node Node_cp(struct Node* member);
```

And finally, you have to free the memory you have allocated dynamically using : `free(NewMember);`