# typedef struct vs struct - storage size of ‘struct' isn’t known

Tags: c++, c, struct

I am trying myself out at bluetooth programming and came along this problem I do not understand. Basically, when I am using the typedef struct defintion the compiler throws the error:

`temp_testcode.c:11:23: error: storage size of ‘head’ isn’t known`

The code, compiled simply via `gcc temp_testcode.c` is as follows:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    uint8_t     code;
    uint8_t     ident;
    uint16_t    len;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) l2cap_cmd_hdr;

/**
struct l2cap_cmd_hdr {
    uint8_t     code;
    uint8_t     ident;
    uint16_t    len;
};
*/

int main(int argc ,char* argv[]) {
    struct l2cap_cmd_hdr head;
}
```

Though once I use the lower definition of a struct (currently commented out) the code compiles perfectly fine. So either it's a problem with the *typedef struct* or with the __attribute__ ((packed))

The previous stackoverflow posts about typedef structs did not help me out ([typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)), since **I do not know how to make the the struct initialization in the main method work using the *typedef struct*** (and not my currently commented out version). Something which is necessary because the bluetooth header files all define their structs like this.

So:

- How do I make the struct initialization in the main method work using the *typedef struct*?
- Why doesn't my code work?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Have you tried: `struct l2cap_cmd_hdr head;`-> `l2cap_cmd_hdr head;`

Comment: If you are using typedef then try `l2cap_cmd_hdr head;`

Comment: Alright, that answer already fixed it. I figured it was quite simple. Thank you very much! Though I would still like to know why this is the case.

Comment: If you're using C++, there's no real reason to use a typedef struct. If you're using C, the common idiom is to do both, to avoid having to use `struct` as a keyword to state your class is in-fact a struct. That is, you should never use the word keyword `struct` with a typedef-ed struct, and you shouldn't use typedef-ed structs in C++ (although you should in C++). A common idiom is `typedef struct x {...} x;`, to get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typedefs and structs are in two different namespaces.  That means the typedef `l2cap_cmd_hdr` is distinct from the struct `struct l2cap_cmd_hdr`.

You're trying to create an instance of the latter, which doesn't exist.  You do have an instance of an anonymous struct that is typedef'ed as `l2cap_cmd_hdr`, so you can create that:

```
l2cap_cmd_hdr head;
```

Comment: But each time I do this task it does create a seperate instance of the struct, doesn't it? So `l2cap_cmd_hdr head1; l2cal_cmd_hdr head2;` would be two different instances and wouldn't have the same values in them!?

Comment: @PPP That's correct.  The above statement defines an instance of the referenced struct.  If you only need once instance just create one.  If you need two then create two.