# Why do I get an error "expected expression before ..."?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm new to coding, I'm portuguese, so my English is not so good.

My question:

```
int main()
{
    typedef struct Coiso{
        char cor_cabelo[100];
        int idade;
        float altura;

    }Coiso;


    printf ( "Insira a cor do cabelo do coiso\n");
    scanf ( "%s", Coiso);

    printf ( "%s\n", Coiso.cor_de_cabelo);

return 0;
}
```

So, I compiled this in geany and get an error: `expected expression before "coiso"`.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: You only declare a type `Coiso`, not a variable.

Comment: `Coiso` is a _type_, not a variable

Comment: Sorry my mistake. i have "printf ( "Insira a cor do cabelo do coiso\n");
    scanf ( "%s", Coiso.cor_de_cabelo);

    printf ( "%s\n", Coiso.cor_de_cabelo);

Comment: you might want to give some value to `cor_de_cabelo`

Answer (score 1):

As others have said Coiso is just a custom type, like int or bool. 
You have to declare a variable with it. So to edit your code.

```
Coiso var;

scanf ( "%s", var);

printf ( "%s\n", var.cor_de_cabelo);
```

Comment: `scanf ( "%s", var);` is not correct, it should be `scanf ( "%s", var.cor_de_cabelo);`

Comment: Osiris, i understand the idea. it's perfect. now it's work

Comment: `typedef struct X {...}X; struct {...}X; typedef struct {...} X; struct X X; ...` This could be really confusing when you learn C. I recommend you read this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions. The explanations are realised in a very didactic manner.