# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type - C language

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, definition

A few days ago I made a function, which worked just fine. This is struct defining I used.

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    struct Node * next;
} Node;

typedef struct {
    Node * head;
    Node * current;
    int size;
} List;
```

Then I have this function

```
void returnMiddle(List * list){
    Node * first = list->head;
    Node * second = list->head;

    if(list->head != NULL){
        while(second != NULL && second->next != NULL){
            first = first->next;
            second = first->next->next; 
        }
        printf("Middle is: %d", first->data);
    }
}
```

But now I receive given error and I don't understand why? Does anyone know?

`second = first->next->next;` <<< this is where I get an error message, up to here it works fine

Comment: `struct Node` is not `Node`.

Comment: I used exact same with different function and it worked just fine. I used `Node * p = list->head;` and everything was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  this typedef declaration of a structure

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    struct Node * next;
} Node;
```

the type `struct Node` is an incomplete type. That is the type name `struct Node` is introduced but not defined.

Pay attention that the typedef name Node and the type name struct Node name two different entities. The name `Node` names an unnamed structure while `struct Node` names a not yet defined structure.

It is obvious that you mean the following

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node * next;
} Node;
```

Comment: Thank you, you explained this very well.

Answer (score 1):

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

This means that the compiler couldn't find a definition of the struct within the translation unit where you made that access - it could only find a declaration. `struct Node * next;` is as it turns out, a pointer to a type that wasn't previously defined at the point where you declared it. Because it only becomes defined when the compiler reaches the `};` of the struct.

For a self-referencing struct, you need to forward-declare the type in order to use it as a struct member. Depending on your coding style that either means:

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;  // also possible: Node* next;
};
```

or

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next; 
} Node;
```

(The type `Node` and the struct tag `Node` actually live in separate namespaces, but this is one of those things one need not ponder about - just do.)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Node * next;
```

`struct Node` is a forward declaration to structure `Node`, but you haven´t defined a structure called `Node` yet - means `struct Node` is an incomplete type.

```
typedef struct {
   ...
} Node;
```

`Node` is a typedef for the structure definition. it is not equal to `struct Node`.

---

Provide the structure tag `Node`:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node * next;
} Node;
```

and your code works fine.

---

Also have a look at here:

[typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)