# What is the difference when defining structs with typedef?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Option 1:

```
typedef struct s{
                 int x;
                 double y;
                 char z;
                 }mystruct;
```

Option 2:

```
typedef struct {
                int x;
                double y;
                char z;
                }mystruct;
```

What's the difference between these 2 options?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions) post help?

Comment: @costaparas I couldn't find the answer for the specific nuance I was asking for but I found another useful information

Comment: Option 2 defines mystruct as an anonymous struct. Option 1 defines mystruct as a `struct s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With option 1 you can declare a variable like this:

```
struct s foo;
```

or

```
mystruct foo;
```

With option 2 the only possibility is:

```
mystruct foo;
```