# What role is typedef playing in this block of code?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm new to learning C++ and wanted some clarification on what `typedef` is doing in the block of code below.

```
typedef struct strNode Node;
struct strNode
{
  int number;   
  int weight;   
  list<Node> edges; 
};
```

I understand that `struct strNode` is creating a new datatype but what is `typedef struct strNode Node` doing exactly?

Comment: This is a C-ism. In C it lets you use `Node` instead of `struct strNode`. But in C++ you already can use `strNode` without the `struct` prefix, so the typedef is pointless (and can be shortened to `typedef strNode Node;`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

Comment: If you found this piece of code on a website that claims to be a C++ educational resource, throw that nonsensical website away and take a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Answer (score 1):

> what is `typedef struct strNode Node` doing exactly?

It's creating an alias for `strNode` so that you can use `strNode` and `Node` interchangeably. This setup is usually used in C to be able to use the alias within the `struct` definition:

```c
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node
{
  int number;   
  int weight;   
  Node *next;
};
```

This is not needed in C++. `Node` could here be used directly without `typedef`:

```cpp
struct Node
{
  int number;   
  int weight;   
  std::list<Node> edges;
};
```