# Struct declaration NOT sufficient?

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, declaration, incomplete-type

Having the following C code:

```
struct Point2_s;
struct Point1_s{
  int x;
  int y;
  Point2_s P2;
} Point1;

struct Point2_s{
  int x;
  int y;
} ;


int main() {
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> unknown type name ‘Point2_s’

Can anyone can please explain me WHY it doesn't work? Why doesn't the struct `Point2_s` declaration is insufficient when defining the `Point1_s` member `P2`?

Comment: `Point2_s P2;` should be `struct Point2_s P2;`. If you want to be able to use the structure name without putting `struct` before it, use `typedef` to define an alias for it.

Comment: It's not possible for the compiler to know the size of `Point2_s` without its definition. That's okay for pointers, but not for struct fields, which affect the outer struct's size and alignment.

Comment: OT: `Point2` contains xy for **one** point. `Point1` contains xy for **two** points... Is the point of this to confuse the reader?

Comment: In C, if you define a type `struct Foo`, its name is `struct Foo`, **not** `Foo`. You can use a typedef if you also want to call it `Foo`; I discussed this at some length [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26389105/827263). (In C++, if you define a type `struct Foo`, you can refer to it as `Foo`; C++ is a different language.) This is in addition to the issues about incomplete types that others have discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
struct Point2_s;
```

there is declared an incomplete structure specifier `struct Point2_s`.

In this declaration

```
struct Point1_s{
  int x;
  int y;
  Point2_s P2;
} Point1;
```

there is used an unknown name `Point2_s`. It is not the same as `struct Point2_s`.

But even if you will write

```
struct Point1_s{
  int x;
  int y;
  struct Point2_s P2;
} Point1;
```

nevertheless you may not use an incomplete type in a data member declaration.

From the C Standard (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 3 **A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or
> function type** (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of
> itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), except
> that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
> may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union
> containing, possibly recursively, a member that is such a structure)
> shall not be a member of a structure or an element of an array.

Instead you need to write

```
struct Point2_s{
  int x;
  int y;
} ;

struct Point1_s{
  int x;
  int y;
  struct Point2_s P2;
} Point1;
```

Or you could write

```
typedef struct Point2_s{
  int x;
  int y;
} Point2_s;

struct Point1_s{
  int x;
  int y;
  Point2_s P2;
} Point1;
```

In this case the name `Point2_s` is an alias for the type specifier `struct Point2_s`.

On the other hand, as it is pointed out in other answers you may use pointers to incomplete types because pointers themselves are always complete types. That is you may write

```
struct Point2_s;
struct Point1_s{
  int x;
  int y;
  struct Point2_s *P2;
} Point1;
```

Comment: So the same applies to the class'es in c++? Right? Am i right that so the declarations is NOT sufficient for custom data types like structs and/or classes because it can have various size but why is it sufficient for functions - one can ONLY have function declaration before function invocation?

Comment: @darro911 In C++ you may use structure names without the keyword struct. But in any case a data member shall be a complete type that is the size of an object of the type shall be known.

Comment: Ok I know that , but am I right that in case of functions the declaration is enought before the function call?

Comment: @darro911 Function parameters if it is not a function definition may be incomplete types. When for example a function parameter has an array type of unknown size the compiler adjusts it to pointer to the array element type as ant other array type..

Comment: So to summarize: We CAN have function declarations BUT NOT struct/class?

Comment: @darro911: Function declarations are enough to reserve room for the call in the compiled code; it doesn't need the actual function until the linker gets involved. That's why they work, while forward declaration for `struct`s/`class`es of unknown size aren't enough to declare anything but a (fixed size) pointer to them (you can't even access the contents until the actual declaration has occurred).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thx. That's the answer i expected - short and clear.:-)

Answer (score 2):

A forward declaration can only be used to declare *pointers* to the forward-declared struct. It doesn't know how big it is though, so it can't use the type directly (how does it know how much space to reserve for the `P2` member?).

Just reverse the order of declaration:

```
struct Point2_s{
  int x;
  int y;
};

struct Point1_s{
  int x;
  int y;
  struct Point2_s P2;  // You didn't typedef, so by the C standard, you need struct to declare the member
} Point1;
```

or you'll need to use pointers:

```
struct Point2_s;
struct Point1_s{
  int x;
  int y;
  struct Point2_s *P2; // Pointer, again adding struct; P2 will need to be allocated separately, e.g. by malloc
} Point1;

struct Point2_s{
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaration will not work in this case (abstracting from missing `struct`) as compiler needs to know the size of the member `P2`. You need to declare it **before** the the declaration which uses it.

```
struct Point2_s{
  int x;
  int y;
} ;

struct Point1_s{
  int x;
  int y;
  struct Point2_s P2;
} Point1;
```

Forward declaration will only work only for pointers:

```
struct Point2_s;

struct Point1_s{
  int x;
  int y;
  struct Point2_s *P2;
} Point1;

struct Point2_s{
  int x;
  int y;
} ;
```