# How is the typedef struct code used in C?

Tags: c, typedef

I have to add the roots to an custom datatype which is roots in this case.
(This is what I think about this issue)

So how do I do this?
Here is my code:

```
#include <math.h>

typedef struct { double m, n; } roots;

roots *quadratic_formula(int a, int b, int c) {

    double root1,root2;
  
    root1 = ((-b)+sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
    root2 = ((-b)-sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
    
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Simply declare an instance of type `roots` and initialize the members.

Comment: I dont actually know anything about typedef , it will be easier to understand if you can provide the code.

Comment: @ikegami already did. But this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1675351/20017547

Comment: You can't return a pointer to a `struct` here unless you allocate dynamic memory for it. For a small `struct` like that it would be easier to have say `roots result; ... return result;` and remove the `*` from the function definition.

Comment: It might be better to pass a pointer argument to the caller's `struct` and make the function type `bool` so that it can `return false` when *b² < 4ac*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This creates a type called `Roots`:

```c
typedef struct { double m, n; } Roots;
```

(I renamed the type to `Roots` to allow a variable named `roots`.)

As always, you can create a variable of that type using `Type var;`.

```c
Roots roots;
```

Then, it's just a question of assigning to the members of the underlying struct.

```c
roots.m = ((-b)+sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
roots.n = ((-b)-sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
```

You can even combine the variable declaration and the initialization.

```c
Roots roots = {
   ((-b)+sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a),
   ((-b)-sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a),
};
```

Finally, returning the variable can be done using

```c
return roots;
```

You'll need to declare the function with the correct return type. (There's no pointer involved here.)

```c
Roots quadratic_formula(int a, int b, int c) {
   double t1 = -b;
   double t2 = sqrt( b*b - 4*a*c );
   double t3 = 2*a;

   Roots roots = {
      ( t1 + t2 ) / t3,
      ( t1 - t2 ) / t3,
   };

   return roots;
}
```

One could even use an anonymous variable.

```c
Roots quadratic_formula(int a, int b, int c) {
   double t1 = -b;
   double t2 = sqrt( b*b - 4*a*c );
   double t3 = 2*a;

   return (Roots){
      ( t1 + t2 ) / t3,
      ( t1 - t2 ) / t3,
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your data type inputs (int) are probably not what you want. Attempting to compute sqrts or divisions using integers is not going to end well. Try using double instead?

```cpp
typedef struct { double m, n; } roots;

roots quadratic_formula(double a, double b, double c) {

    double root1,root2;
  
    root1 = ((-b)+sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
    root2 = ((-b)-sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
    
    return {root1, root2};
}
```

Now for the bigger problems.

`(b*b)-4*a*c)` can be negative, in which case the quadratic does not have a solution.

```cpp
typedef struct { double m, n; int has_solution; } roots;

roots quadratic_formula(double a, double b, double c) {

    double root1,root2;

    double discriminant = (b*b)-4.0*a*c);
    if(discriminant < 0) {
        return (roots) { 0, 0, 0 };
    }

    root1 = ((-b)+sqrt(discriminant)/(2*a);
    root2 = ((-b)-sqrt(discriminant)/(2*a);
    
    return {root1, root2, 1};
}
```

If `a` is equal to zero, the equation is not a quadratic, and will need to be solved as a linear equation. If `b` is also zero, the equation has no solution.

```cpp
typedef struct { double m, n; int has_solution; } roots;

roots quadratic_formula(double a, double b, double c) {

    // if linear
    if(a == 0) {
        if(b == 0) return {0,0,0}; // no solution
        double root = -c / b;
        return {root, root, 1};
    }

    double root1,root2;

    double discriminant = (b*b)-4.0*a*c);

    // quadratic is always above the y = 0 line
    if(discriminant < 0) {
        return (roots) { 0, 0, 0 };
    }

    root1 = ((-b)+sqrt(discriminant)/(2*a);
    root2 = ((-b)-sqrt(discriminant)/(2*a);
    
    return {root1, root2, 1};
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem i was solving already provided the condition that inputs will be non-zero ints and there will never be imaginary roots.