# Using a struct to manipulate a structs parameter value via a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm currently trying to work on a process creation program, and was hoping for some insights. I want to make an array of Process pointers, and use a process to manipulate the value of another process. I simplified the Process struct for this example. In this case, arrayP[1] is the child of arrayP[0], and I was looking to change the value of arrayP[0]'s number of children to 1 using arrayP[1]'s pointer to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MIN_PID 300
#define MAX_PID 5000

typedef struct {
    int numChildren;
    struct Process* parent;
} Process;

int main(void)
{
    Process *arrayP;
    arrayP=malloc(sizeof(Process)*2);

    arrayP[1].parent=&arrayP[0];
    arrayP[1].parent->numChildren = 1;

    free(arrayP);

    return 0;
}
```

when this is compiled, I get the error:

```
incomplete definition of type 'struct Process'
p2.parent->numChildren = 1;
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this just not possible?

Comment: At minimum, [`typedef struct` vs `struct` definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1675351/15168) should be read.  I think this is likely a duplicate of that.

Comment: OT: Looking for trouble? Use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`... At least a NULL pointer will give consistent problems (instead of the program _appearing_ to work on even numbered days, but only in the afternoon...)

Answer (score 3):

Just update Process struct definition as

```
typedef struct Process {
    int numChildren;
    struct Process* parent;
} Process;
```

Comment: Strictly, there is no `struct Process` defined in the code in the question.  There is an anonymous `struct` with the typedef name `Process`, but that is unrelated to `struct Process`.  Your fix is correct — add the tag so that `struct Process` is known at the point when the `parent` element is defined.  You can only use a pointer to the type, as the code does; it is still an incomplete type at that point and is not completed until the close brace is reached.

Comment: Ok I edited the answer to removedthe confusing part of the answer description.

Answer (score 3):

Compiling your code with warnings on:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:19:21: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     arrayP[1].parent=&arrayP[0];
                     ^
test.c:20:21: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Process’
     arrayP[1].parent->numChildren = 1;
                     ^~
```

But, if we fix your struct definition, it compiles cleanly.

```c
typedef struct Process {
    int numChildren;
    struct Process* parent;
} Process;
```

In the original code, an anonymous struct is typedefed to `Process`, but there's never a `struct Process` that we can specify a pointer to.

We could also remove the typedef to a separate statement *before* the struct definition.

```c
typedef struct Process Process;

struct Process {
    int numChildren;
    Process *parent;
};
```