# How to use a typedef tagless struct with a struct tag?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm using the libbson C library to work with MongoDB. In this library, every defined struct is tagless with a typedef alias, e.g. [the bson_t struct](https://mongoc.org/libbson/current/bson_t.html):

```
typedef struct {
   uint32_t flags;       /* Internal flags for the bson_t. */
   uint32_t len;         /* Length of BSON data. */
   uint8_t padding[120]; /* Padding for stack allocation. */
} bson_t
```

I would like to use all my struct types by explicitly typing `struct name`, so in this case, it would be `struct bson_t`. It's just personal preference, no offence for everyone.

If the library had defined the above using `typedef struct bson_t { ... } bson_t` it would have been possible, but as of now, the only way I have to use the `bson_t` type is without the `struct` prefix.

Is there anything that I can do to make the `struct bson_t` refer to the `bson_t` type? Besides editing the `mongoc.h` file, that is.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not an anonymous `struct`. It is taagless. It is something completely different. I do not think that it is possible to add tag to alias

Comment: Thanks @gulpr for the clarification about "tagless" vs "anonymous".

Comment: `struct bson_t` would be a different type than the tagless `struct` used to define `bson_t`.

Comment: It is generally considered bad programming to divert from the existing style of the code base, regardless of your personal preferences. The solution is to fall in line and use the same style as the rest of the project. Notably the style used here is also by far the most common one used in C, so "my best bet is to raise a concern with the library authors" would just be childish.

Comment: @Lundin I personally don't think it would be childish to ask them to support both styles. It would be just as simple as doing `typedef struct bson_t { ... } bson_t`, instead of leaving it tagless.

Comment: Why would they allow 2 different styles in the same code base? That just makes everything less readable and fishy-looking.

Comment: Because that wouldn't hurt readability at all (how can `typedef struct bson_t { ... } bson_t` be less readable than `typedef struct { ... } bson_t`?) and for the same reason wouldn't be fishy-looking. Also your argument "the style used here is by far the most common one used in C" doesn't seem to be true: [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1675446). The [Linux kernel code style guide](https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html) itself recommends to make `struct` explicit, and I would argue that it's a good amount of lines of code against the "common styie".

Comment: A lot of the `struct`s have already had tags for several years, e.g. `typedef struct _bson_t { ` … `} bson_t;`. The underscore prefix is probably there because the authors expect the `typedef` names to be used externally.

Comment: I suppose one concern is that POSIX reserves the `_t` suffix in all type names for future use in POSIX interfaces, but most projects ignore that. (It's unlikely to matter to projects that try and avoid excessive namespace pollution by adopting a common prefix (or prefixes), for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C 2018 6.7.2.3 5 says:

> … Each declaration of a structure, union, or enumerated type which does not include a tag declares a distinct type.

and:

> Two declarations of structure, union, or enumerated types which are in different scopes or use different tags declare distinct types…

So any declaration of a structure with a tag declares a distinct type from any structure without a tag. The C standard does not provide any way to make them the same type.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that's unfortunate. Since there's no way around, my best bet is to raise a concern with the library authors.

Comment: @FrancescoBallardin If I were one of those library authors, I'd treat the concern with the contempt it deserves!

Comment: @IanAbbott good thing you are not the author then!