In "C". Combining arrays and structure items
I'm attempting to combine arrays and structs, but still work with arrays as normal.
This is what I've tried. And theirs errors attach to it.
int arryboard[10] = {
    struct myitems {
        char cname[40];
        int location;
        int idval;
    } itemaccess;
}

can this happen??  arryboard[##].location = 0; 
                   strcpy(arryboard[##].cname,"\0");
                   ++arryboard[##].location; 
        but still manipulate thru the array arryboard. 

Can I still do this??
Thanks as usual.
As mentioned above, I've been trying to put arrays and structures together, but with no  success. In past projects, I've used arrays and structures separately with great success. How can I combine them and make them work.
Thanks
The article: "copying C-style arrays and structure" touches on this question of mine but not really.

You can't define a struct inside of an array. You need to define the struct outside of the array as its element type, eg:
struct myitems {
    char cname[40];
    int location;
    int idval;
}
arryboard[10] = {
    ...
};

Alternatively, as a separate type declaration:
typedef struct myitems {
    char cname[40];
    int location;
    int idval;
} myitems;

myitems arryboard[10] = {
    ...
};


Do you need myitems twice in your typedef version?

@matt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/
