# return a local variable from function in C

Tags: c

I found a similar question and solutions for that here - [returning a local variable from function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c)

But came up with another solution for same issue and would like to ask you to evaluate it, is it correct or not?

```
int myfunction (char **returnval) {
    int isvalue = 0;
    char *d;
    d = "Lorem";
    *returnval = d;
    return isvalue;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int func_return;
    char *myvar;

    func_return = myfunction(&myvar);
    printf("myvar=[%s]\n", myvar);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: myvar=[Lorem]

Is that code correct? The memory used by vars won't be lost because of function scope?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String literals are static, i.e. the memory used to hold the characters `Lorem` is not used to hold anything else for the duration of the program. Thus, returning an address to such a string is safe.

This is the same as doing

```
const char* myfunction(void)
{
  return "Lorem";
}
```

which is perfectly fine and a common thing to do, for instance when mapping `enum` values to symbolic strings:

```
typedef enum { Error_FileNotFound, Error_OutOfMemory, Error_PrinterOnFire } ErrorCode;

const char * error_code_to_string(ErrorCode error)
{
  switch(errorCode)
  {
  case Error_FileNotFound:
    return "Error_FileNotFound";
  case Error_OutOfMemory:
    return "Error_OutOfMemory";
  case Error_PrinterOnFire:
    return "Error_PrinterOnFire";
  return "Unknown error";
  }
}
```

Code like this is often (in practice) made way harder to read by making it more DRY, using macros to implement the `case` statements.

Comment: I'd give another +1 for **const** char *

Answer (score 2):

"Lorem" is static. as you can see, you never defined him in the code.

If you would have done:

```
char[6] d;
```

and you would copy there the value and try to return it you would have a problem