# puzzled with the output

Tags: c, printf, local-variables

why does printf prints 7 although the variable a was local to the function fun() and should     no longer exist once the control returns from function fun().

Here is the c code

```
‎#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int *fun();
    int *c=fun();
    printf("%d",*c);
    getch();
}

int *fun()
{
    int a=7;
    return(&a);
}
```

output : 7

Comment: possible duplicate of [returning a local variable from function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

This is because even if the variable does not exist anymore, the memory location where it was has not yet been used for something else. Hence, the pointer still points to a memory location where the bits contains an `int` with value 7.

But this is definitely **undefined behavior**. You *should not rely on it*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the language idioms and the physical operation of the hardware. In "C" words, yes, your variable should not be accessed anymore, but physically the variable `a` has been allocated on the stack of your program, which is not erased each time a function returns (it would take too much time), thus you can still read it.

Anyway, this is not recommended because other function calls may erase this data.

Comment: but why does this code always prints the garbage ?
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
char *s;
char *fun();
s=fun();
printf("\nhello..1\n");
printf("%s",s);
getch();
}
char *fun()
{
char str[30];
strcpy(str,"this is too simple\0"); 
return(str);
}

Comment: Because you don't do anything else between the function call (stack initialization and returning a pointer to the variable in the stack) and the `printf` of the value pointed by that variable. Chances are that if you call others functions you will read something else. EDIT: for example your code print a garbage string on my system.

Answer (score 1):

once the fun() return, the frame pointer has been set back to point the main() frame again. the pointer c pointed to some address in the memory, since the fun() has already returned, we don't know what's in the adress,but if nothing else has been written to the adress, it can still be the previous variable a. the C standard simply move the frame pointer when a function returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are printing *c , which displays the value which is stored on the location i.e &a , just try to print c then you will get the address of 7 .

It is because the address is already passed to the variable c and the memory address can be read outside the function as well

Comment: But we are not *allowed* to read that memory address outside of the function.

Comment: @BoPersson But the value of memory address is already passed to another variable i.e c .

Comment: But as `a` isn't there anymore, reading from `*c` is not allowed either. This is undefined behavior and *anything* can happen, including `printf` outputting 7 (or 42, or crash).

Comment: @BoPersson a is not there but it is not completely deleted too , the value of a is saved in the memory until we don't delete it ourselves .