# Junk value from string using C

Tags: c

I'm not sure what's going on with my program, but I basically have a function that's trying to read a bunch of strings from a file and passes it back to main for further processing. Here's my code:

```
char* readFile(FILE* fpFile)
{
//  Local Declaration
char *ptr;
char temp[1000];

//  Statment
fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), fpFile);
ptr = temp;

return ptr;
}// readFile
```

The problem occurs once the function passes back the pointer to main. I tried printing the string, but I only get the first few lines correct and after it's junk. Also, if I were to print `ptr` in the function `readFile` it prints perfectly fine and the pointer that's being passed back to main prints fine also. Is there something that I am missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the output I'm getting

```
2000 1990
New York-No. NJ; 21199865 19549649
Los Angeles area; 16373645 14531629
Chicago area; 9157540 8239820
Washington-Baltimore; 7608070 6727050
San Francisco area; 7039362 6253311
Philadelphia-Atlantic City area; 6188463 5892937
Boston\240\365\277_\377
```

There's supposed to be twice the amount of inputs, but it's stoping like a quarter of the way.

Comment: OH NO!

You had better take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char temp[1000];` is local. when the control goes out of `readFile()`, that memory may be allocated to some other purpose. There are two ways, either storage may be a global array or dynamically allocated memory using `malloc()`.

```
char* readFile(FILE* fpFile)
{
//  Local Declaration
char *ptr = malloc(1000);

//  Statment
fgets(ptr, 1000, fpFile);

return ptr;
}// readFile
```

Comment: Do not advice global arrays, please. Instead, it is common to ask caller to provide storage. Also, `sizeof(char) === 1` by standard.

Comment: @Jeyaram Thanks, for pointing my issue. I will definitely keep this in mind and apply for future uses.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is only guaranteed to live within the scope of the function. This includes the data you allocated for `temp`. Afterwords, anything can and will happen to those `1000` cells.

There is a second thing that is wrong with your function:
It seems to be wrapping an existing function that already provides your target functionality.

Was

```
char* readFile(FILE* fpFile)
{
//  Local Declaration
char *ptr;
char temp[1000];

//  Statment
fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), fpFile);
ptr = temp;

return ptr;
}// readFile
```

Works

```
char* readFile(FILE* fpFile, char* ptr, int n)
{
//  Statment
fgets(ptr, sizeof(char)*n, fpFile);
ptr = temp;
return ptr;
}// readFile
void fun()
{
//somehow File*
int num = 1000;
char* pointer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*num);
pointer = readFile(file,pointer,num);
}
```

Should Be

```
void fun()
{
//somehow File*
int num = 1000;
char* pointer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*num);
fgets(file,pointer*sizeof(char));
}
```